# Reloading the page gives wrong GET request with AngularJS HTML5 mode

Tags: angularjs, html, angular-routing

I want to enable HTML5 mode for my app. I have put the following code for the configuration, as shown [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.$location):

```
return app.config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider', function($routeProvider,$locationProvider) {

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $locationProvider.hashPrefix = '!';

    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl: '/views/index.html',
        controller: 'indexCtrl'
    });
    $routeProvider.when('/about',{
        templateUrl: '/views/about.html',
        controller: 'AboutCtrl'
    });
```

As you can see, I used the `$locationProvider.html5mode` and I changed all my links at the `ng-href` to exclude the `/#/`.

### The Problem

At the moment, I can go to `localhost:9000/` and see the index page and navigate to the other pages like `localhost:9000/about`.

However, the problem occurs when I refresh the `localhost:9000/about` page. I get the following output: `Cannot GET /about`

If I look at the network calls:

```
Request URL:localhost:9000/about
Request Method:GET
```

While if I first go to `localhost:9000/` and then click on a button that navigates to `/about` I get:

```
Request URL:http://localhost:9000/views/about.html
```

Which renders the page perfectly.

**How can I enable angular to get the correct page when I refresh?**

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22394014/how-to-correct-set-root-route-in-rails-4-for-angularjs/22460542#22460542

Comment: I solve it for me. See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22394014/how-to-correct-set-root-route-in-rails-4-for-angularjs/22460542#22460542

Answer (score 99, accepted):

From the [angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location)

> **Server side**
>   Using this mode requires URL rewriting on server side, basically you have to rewrite all your links to entry point of your application (e.g. index.html)

The reason for this is that when you first visit the page (`/about`), e.g. after a refresh, the browser has no way of knowing that this isn't a real URL, so it goes ahead and loads it. However if you have loaded up the root page first, and all the javascript code, then when you navigate to `/about` Angular can get in there before the browser tries to hit the server and handle it accordingly

Comment: When it says "you have to rewrite all your links to the entry point of your application (e.g. index.html)" what does this mean? Does it mean I have to go into my `$routeProvider` and change the paths of each `templateUrl` e.g. from `templateUrl : '/views/about.html',` to `templateUrl : 'example.com/views/about.html',`?

Comment: No, your rules in $routeProvider should stay as they are. The answer refers to "server side". It refers to changing the routing on the server that provides your angular html pages. Before each request gets to your angular app, it has to pass first through server-side routing, which should rewrite all requests to point to your angular app entry point (e.g. 'index.html', or '/', depending how your angular routes work).

Comment: In case if I serve my minified index.html via some CDN than how will this routing mechanism will executes ??

Comment: You'll need to make sure all requests somehow get to index.html. Maybe the CDN will allow you to configure this or you'll have to get the CDN to pass through all requests to some origin server that does this itself (e.g. point your CDN at simple nginx server that always serves up index.html regardless of the path). However if you're frequently updating index.html then having a CDN in the way may be more trouble than its worth.

Comment: what type of changes i can in server side. Is i change something in .htaccess file

Comment: yes - have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22739455/htaccess-redirect-for-angular-routes

Comment: Good article for apache, there is an htaccess exemple : https://ngmilk.rocks/2015/03/09/angularjs-html5-mode-or-pretty-urls-on-apache-using-htaccess/

Comment: After fixing server side with node/express route config I'm still seeing a different error trying to refresh at a given url.  So base is /report  and if I navigate from base to /report/test it works, but refresh, server side does go to to base but I get this angular error Error: $injector:modulerr
Module Error.      Seems like some timing issue still, like Angular having problems initiating from non base location

Comment: how can i configure it in localhost

Answer (score 64):

There are few things to set up so your link in the browser will look like `http://yourdomain.com/path` and these are your angular config + server side

**1) AngularJS**

```
$routeProvider
  .when('/path', {
    templateUrl: 'path.html',
  });
$locationProvider
  .html5Mode(true);
```

**2) server side,** just put `.htaccess` inside your root folder and paste this

```
RewriteEngine On 
Options FollowSymLinks

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /#/$1 [L]
```

More interesting stuff to read about html5 mode in angularjs and the configuration required per different environment https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode
Also this question might help you [$location / switching between html5 and hashbang mode / link rewriting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16677528/location-switching-between-html5-and-hashbang-mode-link-rewriting)

Comment: Hi. I tried the above solution , made changes in my config file. But still it doesnt work. Refreshing the URL still gives the "404 NOT FOUND" error.

Comment: How do I redirect/rewrite in app deployed in Websphere?

Comment: I don't see why not !

Answer (score 37):

I had a similar problem and I solved it by:

- Using `<base href="/index.html">` in the index page
- Using a catch all route middleware in my node/Express server as follows (put it after the router):

```
app.use(function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile(__dirname + '/Public/index.html');
});
```

I think that should get you up and running.

If you use an apache server, you might want to mod_rewrite your links. It is not difficult to do. Just a few changes in the config files.

All that is assuming you have html5mode enabled on angularjs.
Now. note that in angular 1.2, declaring a base url is not recommended anymore actually.

Comment: This solution worked for me with setting:  `<base href="/">` and adding the Express routing you suggested. Mucho thanks.

Comment: Tahir Chad, did you still need to use a serverside url-rewrite after implementing the `<base href="/index.html">`?

Comment: Yes, you can see url rewriting as a way to set the base url of your application/website in stone (domain included). The 'base url' html statement is just a way to ensure that all relative links are correctly derived from the same base. Base url is not absolutely necessary if your links are absolute.

Comment: Where should I make the express change in cordova app?

Comment: When I use this, I just see the html code itself on the page, not rendered as an actual page.

Comment: This answer deserves triple stars! Thanks for providing such a straightforward answer. Everyone else just repeats the same line about "needing to do server redirecting".

Comment: Nice answer, it appears to be the only one suitable for an Angular2 Chrome extension, using a wildcard to catch missing routes.

Comment: but due to this EVERY http request will have index file,Like eg : /getJsonFromServer - an http request that returns json but due to this configuration it will also return index page

Comment: I suggest you put <base href="/index.html" /> right after <head> not on end of </head>. Because I had css that needed to be served from node.js and it didn't work when it was before the base tag

Answer (score 27):

Solution for BrowserSync and Gulp.

From https://github.com/BrowserSync/browser-sync/issues/204#issuecomment-102623643

First install `connect-history-api-fallback`:

```
npm --save-dev install connect-history-api-fallback
```

Then add it to your gulpfile.js:

```
var historyApiFallback = require('connect-history-api-fallback');

gulp.task('serve', function() {
  browserSync.init({
    server: {
      baseDir: "app",
      middleware: [ historyApiFallback() ]
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Oh snap!  Finally relief from Angular view development!  And as a bonus, standard URLs (without a hash-bang) route too!  Thank you!

Comment: Works like a charm... Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you're using a specific port (i.e. the Ionic blank template runs on port 8100), just add an additional property after server i.e. ```server: { ... }, port: 8100```, then just add the ```serve``` task to your default gulp task (i.e. ```gulp.task('default', ['sass', 'serve']);```), and then you can run the app without the ```Cannot GET ...``` browser errors when you refresh the page by running ```gulp``` . Note that running the server with ```ionic serve``` still encounters the errors.

Comment: This works well when I use development browsersync, in prod I am running the application as express app and redirecting all the route to angular app as app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    req.session.valid = true;
    res.redirect('/');
});
The page does not load when give the path directly ?

Answer (score 15):

You need to configure your server to rewrite everything to index.html to load the app:

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#wiki-how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode

Comment: Perfect, problem for me was using Laravel Forge to provision the server, which had the relevant nginx line as `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?...` instead of the needed `index.html`. Thanks for the link!

Comment: Should be top answer, Gives every situation no matter your server. Worked perfectly with NodeJS

Answer (score 10):

I wrote a simple connect middleware for simulating url-rewriting on grunt projects. https://gist.github.com/muratcorlu/5803655

You can use like that:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  var urlRewrite = require('grunt-connect-rewrite');

  // Project configuration.
  grunt.initConfig({
    connect: {
      server: {
        options: {
          port: 9001,
          base: 'build',
          middleware: function(connect, options) {
            // Return array of whatever middlewares you want
            return [
              // redirect all urls to index.html in build folder
              urlRewrite('build', 'index.html'),

              // Serve static files.
              connect.static(options.base),

              // Make empty directories browsable.
              connect.directory(options.base)
            ];
          }
        }
      }
    }
  })
};
```

Comment: Is there a manual way to accomplish URL re-writing in the `$routeProvider`?

Comment: I get `urlRewrite` is not defined warning when trying to run it, and I'm having a hard time finding the right connect with rewrite that I can use.

Comment: Shows me an error "Object build has no method 'initConfig' Use --force to continue."

Answer (score 8):

If you are in .NET stack with MVC with AngularJS, this is what you have to do to remove the '#'  from url:

1. Set up your base href in your _Layout page: `<head> <base href="/"> </head>`
2. Then, add following in your angular app config : `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)`
3. Above will remove '#' from url but page refresh won't work e.g. if you are in "yoursite.com/about" page refresh will give you a 404. This is because MVC does not know about angular routing and by MVC pattern it will look for a MVC page for 'about' which does not exists in MVC routing path. Workaround for this is to send all MVC page request to a single MVC view and you can do that by adding a route that catches all url

---

```
routes.MapRoute(
        name: "App",
        url: "{*url}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
    );
```

Answer (score 8):

**IIS URL Rewrite Rule to prevent 404 error after page refresh in html5mode**

For angular running under IIS on Windows

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="AngularJS" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

**NodeJS / ExpressJS Routes to prevent 404 error after page refresh in html5mode**

For angular running under Node/Express

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var router = express.Router();

// serve angular front end files from root path
router.use('/', express.static('app', { redirect: false }));

// rewrite virtual urls to angular app to enable refreshing of internal pages
router.get('*', function (req, res, next) {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve('app/index.html'));
});

module.exports = router;
```

More info at: [AngularJS - Enable HTML5 Mode Page Refresh Without 404 Errors in NodeJS and IIS](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/07/26/AngularJS-enable-html5mode-page-refresh-without-404-error-in-NodeJS-and-IIS.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, the IIS rules helped me with an angular2 app deployed in azure which was failing to direct to a child route.

Comment: I cannot thank you enough for the solution for IIS (localhost in VS 2013). Banged my head long enough in frustration, finally found this answer. Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 5):

As others have mentioned, you need to rewrite routes on the server and set `<base href="/"/>`.

For `gulp-connect`:

`npm install connect-pushstate`

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
  connect = require('gulp-connect'),
  pushState = require('connect-pushstate/lib/pushstate').pushState;
...
connect.server({
  ...
  middleware: function (connect, options) {
    return [
      pushState()
    ];
  }
  ...
})
....
```

Answer (score 4):

I am using apache (xampp) on my dev environment and apache on the production,
add:

```
errorDocument 404 /index.html
```

to the .htaccess solve for me this issue.

Answer (score 4):

For Grunt and Browsersync use connect-modrewrite [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-modrewrite)

```
var modRewrite = require('connect-modrewrite');    


browserSync: {
            dev: {
                bsFiles: {

                    src: [
                        'app/assets/css/*.css',
                        'app/*.js',
                        'app/controllers/*.js',
                        '**/*.php',
                        '*.html',
                        'app/jade/includes/*.jade',
                        'app/views/*.html',
               ],
            },
        options: {
            watchTask: true,
            debugInfo: true,
            logConnections: true,
            server: {
                baseDir :'./',
                middleware: [
                       modRewrite(['!\.html|\.js|\.jpg|\.mp4|\.mp3|\.gif|\.svg\|.css|\.png$ /index.html [L]'])
                ]
            },

            ghostMode: {
                scroll: true,
                links: true,
                forms: true
                    }
                }
            }
        },
```

Comment: there are 15 above this answer that were a waist of time. 1. `npm install connect-modrewrite --save` 2. `require in gruntfile` 3. copy the above server obj

Comment: Thanks this worked for me in gulp 4 with browserSync setup.

Comment: Glad it helped @Abdeali Chandanwala!

Comment: @Omar I disagree with you, less advanced users such as myself benefit from seeing how to add it to the gulpfile. It is best to remember that people have different levels of knowledge and just writing require in gruntfile would not be helpful as I would be assuming that they understand how to add it to gulp.

Answer (score 3):

I solved to

```
test: {
        options: {
          port: 9000,
          base: [
            '.tmp',
            'test',
            '<%= yeoman.app %>'
          ],
         middleware: function (connect) {
                  return [
                      modRewrite(['^[^\\.]*$ /index.html [L]']),
                      connect.static('.tmp'),
                      connect().use(
                          '/bower_components',
                          connect.static('./bower_components')
                      ),
                      connect.static('app')
                  ];
              }
        }
      },
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm answering this question from the larger question:

> When I add $locationProvider.html5Mode(true), my site will not allow pasting of urls. How do I configure my server to work when html5Mode is true?

When you have html5Mode enabled, the # character will no longer be used in your urls. The # symbol is useful because it requires no server side configuration. Without #, the url looks much nicer, but it also requires server side rewrites. Here are some examples:

For Express Rewrites with AngularJS, you can solve this with the following updates:

```
app.get('/*', function(req, res) {
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/public/app/views/index.html'));
});
```

and

```
<!-- FOR ANGULAR ROUTING -->
<base href="/">
```

and

```
app.use('/',express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

Comment: Thanks its the solution. For Nodejs add to app.js to app.use('/*', index);

Answer (score 2):

I believe your issue is with regards to the server.  The angular documentation with regards to HTML5 mode (at the link in your question) states:

Server side
Using this mode requires URL rewriting on server side, basically you have to rewrite all your links to entry point of your application (e.g. index.html)

I believe you'll need to setup a url rewrite from /about to /.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So when I am on the about page and I refresh, the server should rewrite the url to / ? The problem is that I work with a rails backend that is on a different domain. All communication is by API calls. How would I do those URL rewrites?

Comment: The thing is your app is availabe at your server route of / so when you refresh a url that is /about the browser will request from your server whatever page is at /about (in this case you have no pages there so you need to redirect those back).

Answer (score 2):

We had a server redirect in Express:

```
app.get('*', function(req, res){
    res.render('index');
});
```

and we were still getting page-refresh issues, even after we added the `<base href="/" />`.

Solution: make sure you're using real links in you page to navigate; don't type in the route in the URL or you'll get a page-refresh. (silly mistake, I know)

:-P

Comment: but due to this EVERY http request will have index file,Like eg : /getJsonFromServer - an http request that returns data but due to this configuration it will also return index page

Answer (score 1):

Finally I got a way to to solve this issue by server side as it's more like an issue with AngularJs itself I am using 1.5 Angularjs and I got same issue on reload the page.
But after adding below code in my `server.js` file it is save my day ***but it's not a proper solution or not a good way .***

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){
  var d = res.status(404);
     if(d){
        res.sendfile('index.html');
     }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved the issue by adding below code snippet into node.js file.

```
app.get("/*", function (request, response) {
    console.log('Unknown API called');
    response.redirect('/#' + request.url);
});
```

Note : when we refresh the page, it will look for the API instead of Angular page (Because of no # tag in URL.) . Using the above code, I am redirecting to the url with #

Answer (score 0):

I have found even better Grunt plugin, that works if you have your index.html and Gruntfile.js in the same directory;

```
https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-connect-pushstate
```

After that in your Gruntfile:

```
 var pushState = require('grunt-connect-pushstate/lib/utils').pushState;


    connect: {
    server: {
      options: {
        port: 1337,
        base: '',
        logger: 'dev',
        hostname: '*',
        open: true,
        middleware: function (connect, options) {
          return [
            // Rewrite requests to root so they may be handled by router
            pushState(),
            // Serve static files
            connect.static(options.base)
          ];
        }
      },
    }
},
```

Comment: The grunt-connect-pushstate module is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

```
I solved same problem using modRewrite.  
AngularJS is reload page when after # changes.  
But HTML5 mode remove # and invalid the reload.  
So we should reload manually.
# install connect-modrewrite
    $ sudo npm install connect-modrewrite --save

# gulp/build.js
    'use strict';
    var gulp = require('gulp');
    var paths = gulp.paths;
    var util = require('util');
    var browserSync = require('browser-sync');
    var modRewrite  = require('connect-modrewrite');
    function browserSyncInit(baseDir, files, browser) {
        browser = browser === undefined ? 'default' : browser;
        var routes = null;
        if(baseDir === paths.src || (util.isArray(baseDir) && baseDir.indexOf(paths.src) !== -1)) {
            routes = {
                '/bower_components': 'bower_components'
            };
        }

        browserSync.instance = browserSync.init(files, {
            startPath: '/',
            server: {
            baseDir: baseDir,
            middleware: [
                modRewrite([
                    '!\\.\\w+$ /index.html [L]'
                ])
            ],
            routes: routes
            },
            browser: browser
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with **java** + angular app generated with **JHipster**. 
I solved it with Filter and list of all angular pages in properties:

**application.yml:**

```
angular-pages:
  - login
  - settings
...
```

**AngularPageReloadFilter.java**

```
public class AngularPageReloadFilter implements Filter {
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        request.getRequestDispatcher("index.html").forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

**WebConfigurer.java**

```
private void initAngularNonRootRedirectFilter(ServletContext servletContext,
                                              EnumSet<DispatcherType> disps) {
    log.debug("Registering angular page reload Filter");
    FilterRegistration.Dynamic angularRedirectFilter =
            servletContext.addFilter("angularPageReloadFilter",
                    new AngularPageReloadFilter());
    int index = 0;
    while (env.getProperty("angular-pages[" + index + "]") != null) {
        angularRedirectFilter.addMappingForUrlPatterns(disps, true, "/" + env.getProperty("angular-pages[" + index + "]"));
        index++;
    }
    angularRedirectFilter.setAsyncSupported(true);
}
```

Hope, it will be helpful for somebody.

Answer (score 0):

**Gulp + browserSync:**

Install connect-history-api-fallback via npm, later config your serve gulp task

```
var historyApiFallback = require('connect-history-api-fallback');

gulp.task('serve', function() {
  browserSync.init({
    proxy: {
            target: 'localhost:' + port,
            middleware: [ historyApiFallback() ]
        }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your server side code is JAVA then Follow this below steps

step 1 : Download urlrewritefilter JAR [Click Here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.tuckey/urlrewritefilter/4.0.3)
   and save to build path  WEB-INF/lib

step 2 : Enable HTML5 Mode $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

step 3 : set base URL  `<base href="/example.com/"/>`

step 4 : copy and paste to your WEB.XML

```
 <filter>
     <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
 <filter-class>org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

step 5 : create file in WEN-INF/urlrewrite.xml

```
 <urlrewrite default-match-type="wildcard">


    <rule>
            <from>/</from>
            <to>/index.html</to>
        </rule>

    <!--Write every state dependent on your project url-->
    <rule>
            <from>/example</from>
            <to>/index.html</to>
        </rule>
    </urlrewrite>
```

Comment: How to add rule for dynamic url like - 
http://www.test.com/user/101
http://www.test.com/user/102

Answer (score 0):

I have this simple solution I have been using and its works.

**In App/Exceptions/Handler.php**

Add this at top:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;
```

**Then inside the render method**

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    .......

       if ($exception instanceof NotFoundHttpException){

        $segment = $request->segments();

        //eg. http://site.dev/member/profile
        //module => member
        // view => member.index
        //where member.index is the root of your angular app could be anything :)
        if(head($segment) != 'api' && $module = $segment[0]){
            return response(view("$module.index"), 404);
        }

        return response()->fail('not_found', $exception->getCode());

    }
    .......

     return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```