# Livereload Html5 Pushstate with AngularJS, ui.Router and yeoman

Tags: html, mod-rewrite, angularjs-directive, pushstate, connect-modrewrite

I want to fix the livereload with my angular js app. I am using yoeman ui-router with html5 push state.

What do a have to do?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**The index**
For the searchengines you have to add the following to the `<head>` of your index.html

```
<meta name="fragment" content="!">
<base href="/">
```

**The app**
In your app.js you have to inject the following dependencies and add the functions.

```
angular
  .module('yourApp', [
    'ngAnimate',
    'ngCookies',
    'ngResource',
    'ngSanitize',
    'ui.router',
  ])
  .config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {

  // HTML5 PUSH STATE
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

  // STATES
  $stateProvider
    .state('home', {
      url: '/',
      templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
      controller: 'homeCtrl'
    });
});
```

**The middelware**

The solution to this problem is to adapt the connect-modrewrite middleware.

Install the middleware with the node packetmanager within your console in your yeomanfolder

```
npm install connect-modrewrite
```

Then adapt the Gruntfile.js

```
var modRewrite = require('connect-modrewrite');


livereload: {
    options: {
      open: true,
      base: [
        '.tmp',
        '<%= yeoman.app %>'
      ],
      middleware: function (connect, options) {
        var middlewares = [];

        middlewares.push(modRewrite(['^[^\\.]*$ /index.html [L]'])); //Matches everything that does not contain a '.' (period)
        options.base.forEach(function (base) {
          middlewares.push(connect.static(base));
        });

        middlewares.push(
          connect.static('.tmp'),
          connect().use(
            '/bower_components',
            connect.static('./bower_components')
          )
        );

        return middlewares;
      }
    }
  },
```

Now start your grunt with the command

```
grunt serve
```

Comment: I get an error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
   at grunt.initConfig.browserSync.livereload.options.middleware`, the offending line of code is `options.base.forEach(function (base) {`
Is this solution different for later versions? (Nov 2015)