# Error using middleware to redirect grunt server to root

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, yeoman, angularjs-routing, connect-modrewrite

I have tried all solution listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17080494/using-grunt-server-how-can-i-redirect-all-requests-to-root-url?lq=1) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25401114/livereload-html5-pushstate-with-angularjs-ui-router-and-yeoman) but I always end up with an error similar to the one below :

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
   at grunt.initConfig.browserSync.livereload.options.middleware (...
```

or

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function...
```

This question is at least one year later and I realised a lot has changed in grunt so I am not surprised if these answers no longer work.

Is there a new solution to this question for Nov 2015?