# ui-router returns: "Cannot GET /page"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using `ui-router`, and have a `profile` state that looks as follows:

```
.state('profile', {
    url: "/profile",
    templateUrl: "views/profile.html",
    controller: 'ProfileCtrl',
    resolve: {
      currentUser: function(gamAuth){
        return gamAuth.checkCurrentUser(config.userRol.user)
      }
    }
```

When I try to reload/refresh the page I get the following message:

```
Cannot GET /profile
```

The problem does not occur when I reload my 'landing page' at: `http://localhost:9000/`, which has the following state in `$stateProvider`:

```
.state('home', {
    url: "/",
    [...]
})
```

I am using: `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);`

I tried providing absolute URL as suggested in the Decision Tree [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#decision-tree)

I also tried a number of suggestions found online, the most popular being something along these lines (placing it in the `app.run()` section):

```
$state.transitionTo($state.current, $stateParams, {
    reload: true,
    inherit: false,
    notify: true
});
```

All approaches were tested with and without the `<base href="/">` tag being present in the `<head>` of my `index.html`.
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to enable [html5mode](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location) to true if you want to use your url without '#' prefix.

Also you need to add your modRewrtie in as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17080494/using-grunt-server-how-can-i-redirect-all-requests-to-root-url)

**Prerequisite:**

```
npm install --save-dev connect-modrewrite
```

Comment: I am using: `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)` at the moment. Should it be done somehow differently?

Comment: Oh ! If you are already using this, than its problem with your server from where you are serving the site. please let me know how are you serving your project.

Comment: I just tried now, and despite I have (what seems to be) `html5Mode(true)` - I typed `http://localhost:9000/#/profile`, and the page resolves to `/profile` correctly. Does that mean that `html5` should be enable somehow/somewhere differently, rather than using `$locationProvider`?

Comment: yes thats what html5mode do. So i think when you do a reload than its show error "can't GET" am i right?

Comment: Do you know how to change my `Gruntfile.js`, such that it works? I had the contents of my Gruntfile set similar as suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17080494/using-grunt-server-how-can-i-redirect-all-requests-to-root-url), but the problem persists.

Comment: Yes, that what you need. So you should modify your grunt file as mentioned in your link.

Comment: Running the `npm install --save-dev connect-modrewrite` explicitly - solved the problem for me. Thank you very much!

Comment: yes thats the plugin we need to have while applying modrewrite.

Answer (score 1):

When you have html5Mode enabled, the # character will no longer be used in your urls. The # symbol is useful because it requires no server side configuration. Without #, the url looks much nicer, but it also requires server side rewrites.

for more details about Rewrites to be setup:

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.