# AngularJS - UI Router not working (Cannot GET /state)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have defined states using the ui-router like this:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('test.app').config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$locationProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $stateProvider.state('home', {
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: 'home/home.html',
            controller: 'HomeController',
            controllerAs: 'home'
        }).state('about', {
            url: '/about',
            templateUrl: 'about/about.html',
            controller: 'AboutController',
            controllerAs: 'about'
        });

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

        $locationProvider.html5Mode({
            enabled: true,
            requireBase: false
        });
    }])
    .run(['$rootScope', '$templateCache', function($rootScope, $templateCache) {
        $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, next, current) {
            if (typeof(current) !== 'undefined'){
                $templateCache.remove(current.templateUrl);
            }
        });
    }]);
})();
```

I have injected `ui.router` in my app module.

```
angular.module('test.app', [..., 'ui.router'...]
```

home.html:

```
<div data-ui-view>
    <h1>I am home!</h1>
</div>
```

about.html:

```
<div data-ui-view>
    <h1>I am about!</h1>
</div>
```

I am using `browser-sync` to host it on a local server:

```
gulp.task('browserSync', function() {
    browserSync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: "./src"
        },
        port: 8080
    })
});
```

I am facing a strange problem here. The default route `'/'` works perfectly and loads home.html but when i try to access `'/about'` I get the message `Cannot GET /about` in the browser. There are no errors in the console.

I tried this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26904548/ui-router-returns-cannot-get-page) and a few more threads but no good!
Where did I go wrong?

Comment: How're you trying to access `/about`, by typing the URL directly in the browser, or by `ui-sref` or `$state.go`?

Comment: @31piy I am typing it directly in the browser like `http://localhost:8080/about`

Comment: Are you using any server e.g. Node?

Comment: @31piy Yes, I am using node

Comment: In that case, please post your JS files related to Node configuration as well.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion! Actually I am running it using a Gulp configuration utilizing  `browser-sync` as mentioned above.

Comment: When you hit this URL by browser, this request first goes to the server, and then comes to the browser. ui-router can only work on the browser. Please ensure the `/about` is being routed to appropriate view.

Comment: @31piy Okay! Could you be more specific? Seems like the view is appropriate. The same about.html works if put in the default `'/'` route. But any route other than `'/'` is not working.