# AngularJS different ng-app on differnet pages

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am new to Angular JS. I am trying to learn. I have created a project which uses grunt and bower.

This is my project struture

```
MyApp
|
|__app
   |
   |__bower_components
   |
   |__scripts
   | |
   | |__ app.js
   | |
   | |__contollers -- main.js, invoice.js, register.js
   | |
   | |__service -- service.js
   | |
   | |__styles -- CSS files
   | |
   | |__views -- main.html, invoice.html, register.html
   |
   |__ index.html, favicon.ico
```

It contains grunt and karma files also.
Following are my html and js files. (only needed parts)
my **index.html**

```
<body ng-app="MyAppInvoice">
<div class="container" ng-view=""></div>
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
</body>
```

**main.html**

```
<div class="hero-unit">
  <a href="views/registration.html" target="_self">Register</a>
  <a href="#invoice">Invoice</a>
  <br>
</div>
```

**invoice.html** has one form inside a div. And it will come in **div ng-view** of **index.html**.

**register.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="../bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="../scripts/app.js"></script>
<script src="../scripts/controllers/register.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myAppRegister">
<div ng-controller="registerContoller">
<form>
<!-- Form Components -->
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
'use strict';

angular.module('MyAppInvoice', [])
  .config(function ($routeProvider,$locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
          redirectTo: '/main'
        })
      .when('/invoice', {
        templateUrl: 'views/invoice.html',
        controller: 'FileUploadController'
      })
      .when('/main', {
        templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/main'
      });
    /*$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);*/
  });

angular.module('myAppRegister', [])
.config(function ($routeProvider,$locationProvider) {
  /*$routeProvider
        .when('/', {
          redirectTo: '/signUp'
        })
    .when('/signUp', {
      templateUrl: 'views/registration.html',
      controller: 'SignUpController'
    })
    .otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/signUp'
    });*/
});
```

All other JS are working fine.

**1.** In the main page I am putting `<a href="views/registration.html" target="_self">Register</a>` so that the entire page will change instead of ng-view only. But in URL it is displaying like `http://localhost:9000/views/registration.html`. I want to display it as `http://localhost:9000/signUp` only. How can I do that?

**2.** When I click on invoice link it is viewing the invoice page and working fine. But when I add the `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);` (You can see I have commented it) the link URL becomes `http://localhost:9000/main#invoice` instead of `http://localhost:9000/#invoice`

**How can I solve these problems?**

**UPDATE 1**

As gab suggested, I did that. And it is working fine. But the problem is, when I type

`http://localhost:9000/login`, then it shows

```
Cannot GET /login
```

It only works when I click on link. Then I have to start form  `http://localhost:9000/`

Answer (score 3):

you have to make a few changes. First, as Srivastva said, you have to call the route name not the template.

**routes file**:

```
.when('/reg', {
    templateUrl: 'views/registration.html'
})
```

*With html5mode to true* your href tag should be like this:

```
<a href="reg">Register</a>
```

In addition, in order to work you have to add in the HEAD of your document this :

```
<head>
    <base href="/" />
</head>
```

*With html5mode to false* your href tag should be like this:

```
<a href="#/reg">Register</a>
```

To handle html5 on the server I used this angular generator for yeoman. Html5 is bundled, livereload,... Here is the documentation : [angular-generator-fullstack](https://github.com/DaftMonk/generator-angular-fullstack)

Just for information, it may help, here is my grunt file:

```
    // Generated on 2013-12-19 using generator-angular-fullstack 1.0.1
'use strict';

// # Globbing
// for performance reasons we're only matching one level down:
// 'test/spec/{,*/}*.js'
// use this if you want to recursively match all subfolders:
// 'test/spec/**/*.js'

module.exports = function (grunt) {

  // Load grunt tasks automatically
  require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

  // Time how long tasks take. Can help when optimizing build times
  require('time-grunt')(grunt);

  // Define the configuration for all the tasks
  grunt.initConfig({

    // Project settings
    yeoman: {
      // configurable paths
      app: require('./bower.json').appPath || 'app',
      dist: 'public',
      views: 'views'
    },
    express: {
      options: {
        port: process.env.PORT || 9000
      },
      dev: {
        options: {
          script: 'server.js'
        }
      },
      prod: {
        options: {
          script: 'server.js',
          node_env: 'production'
        }
      }
    },
    open: {
      server: {
        url: 'http://127.0.0.1:<%= express.options.port %>'
      }
    },
    watch: {
      js: {
        files: ['{.tmp,<%= yeoman.app %>}/scripts/{,*/}*.js'],
        tasks: ['newer:jshint:all']
      },
      jsTest: {
        files: ['test/spec/{,*/}*.js'],
        tasks: ['newer:jshint:test', 'karma']
      },
      livereload: {
        files: [
          '<%= yeoman.app %>/<%= yeoman.views %>/{,*//*}*.{html,jade}',
          '{.tmp,<%= yeoman.app %>}/styles/{,*//*}*.css',
          '{.tmp,<%= yeoman.app %>}/scripts/{,*//*}*.js',
          '<%= yeoman.app %>/images/{,*//*}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}'
        ],
        options: {
          livereload: true
        }
      },
      compass: {
        files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.{scss,sass}'],
        tasks: ['compass']
      },
      express: {
        files: [
          'server.js',
          'lib/{,*//*}*.{js,json}'
        ],
        tasks: ['express:dev'],
        options: {
          livereload: true,
          nospawn: true //Without this option specified express won't be reloaded
        }
      },
      styles: {
        files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
        tasks: ['newer:copy:styles', 'autoprefixer']
      },
      gruntfile: {
        files: ['Gruntfile.js']
      }
    },

    // Make sure code styles are up to par and there are no obvious mistakes
    jshint: {
      options: {
        jshintrc: '.jshintrc',
        reporter: require('jshint-stylish')
      },
      all: [
        '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js'
      ],
      test: {
        options: {
          jshintrc: 'test/.jshintrc'
        },
        src: ['test/spec/{,*/}*.js']
      }
    },

    // Empties folders to start fresh
    clean: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          dot: true,
          src: [
            '.tmp',
            '<%= yeoman.views %>/*',
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/*',
            '!<%= yeoman.dist %>/.git*'
          ]
        }]
      },

      heroku: {
        files: [{
          dot: true,
          src: [
            'heroku/*',
            '!heroku/.git*',
            '!heroku/Procfile'
          ]
        }]
      },
      server: '.tmp'
    },

    // Add vendor prefixed styles
    autoprefixer: {
      options: {
        browsers: ['last 1 version']
      },
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '.tmp/styles/',
          src: '{,*/}*.css',
          dest: '.tmp/styles/'
        }]
      }
    },


    compass: {
      options: {
        sassDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
        cssDir: '.tmp/styles',
        imagesDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
        javascriptsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts',
        fontsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/fonts',
        importPath: '<%= yeoman.app %>/bower_components',
        relativeAssets: true
      },
      dist: {},
      server: {
        options: {
          debugInfo: true
        }
      }
    },


    // Renames files for browser caching purposes
    rev: {
      dist: {
        files: {
          src: [
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css',
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}',
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/fonts/*'
          ]
        }
      }
    },

    // Reads HTML for usemin blocks to enable smart builds that automatically
    // concat, minify and revision files. Creates configurations in memory so
    // additional tasks can operate on them
    useminPrepare: {
      html: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/<%= yeoman.views %>/index.html',
             '<%= yeoman.app %>/<%= yeoman.views %>/index.jade'],
      options: {
        dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
      }
    },

    // Performs rewrites based on rev and the useminPrepare configuration
    usemin: {
      html: ['<%= yeoman.views %>/{,*/}*.html',
             '<%= yeoman.views %>/{,*/}*.jade'],
      css: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
      options: {
        assetsDirs: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>']
      }
    },

    // The following *-min tasks produce minified files in the dist folder
    imagemin: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
          src: '{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif}',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'
        }]
      }
    },
    svgmin: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
          src: '{,*/}*.svg',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'
        }]
      }
    },
    htmlmin: {
      dist: {
        options: {
          // Optional configurations that you can uncomment to use
          // removeCommentsFromCDATA: true,
          // collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
          // removeAttributeQuotes: true,
          // removeRedundantAttributes: true,
          // useShortDoctype: true,
          // removeEmptyAttributes: true,
          // removeOptionalTags: true*/
        },
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/<%= yeoman.views %>',
          src: ['*.html', 'partials/*.html'],
          dest: '<%= yeoman.views %>'
        }]
      }
    },

    // Allow the use of non-minsafe AngularJS files. Automatically makes it
    // minsafe compatible so Uglify does not destroy the ng references
    ngmin: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '.tmp/concat/scripts',
          src: '*.js',
          dest: '.tmp/concat/scripts'
        }]
      }
    },

    // Replace Google CDN references
    cdnify: {
      dist: {
        html: ['<%= yeoman.views %>/*.html']
      }
    },

    // Copies remaining files to places other tasks can use
    copy: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          dot: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
          src: [
            '*.{ico,png,txt}',
            '.htaccess',
            'bower_components/**/*',
            'images/{,*/}*.{webp}',
            'fonts/*'
          ]
        }, {
          expand: true,
          dot: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/<%= yeoman.views %>',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.views %>',
          src: '**/*.jade'
        }, {
          expand: true,
          cwd: '.tmp/images',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images',
          src: [
            'generated/*'
          ]
        }]
      },
      heroku: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          dot: true,
          dest: 'heroku',
          src: [
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/**',
            '<%= yeoman.views %>/**'
          ]
        }, {
          expand: true,
          dest: 'heroku',
          src: [
            'package.json',
            'server.js',
            'lib/**/*'
          ]
        }]
      },  
      styles: {
        expand: true,
        cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
        dest: '.tmp/styles/',
        src: '{,*/}*.css'
      }
    },

    // Run some tasks in parallel to speed up the build process
    concurrent: {
      server: [
        'copy:styles'
      ],
      test: [
        'copy:styles'
      ],
      dist: [
        'copy:styles',
        'imagemin',
        'svgmin',
        'htmlmin'
      ]
    },

    // By default, your `index.html`'s <!-- Usemin block --> will take care of
    // minification. These next options are pre-configured if you do not wish
    // to use the Usemin blocks.
    // cssmin: {
    //   dist: {
    //     files: {
    //       '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/main.css': [
    //         '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
    //         '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'
    //       ]
    //     }
    //   }
    // },
    // uglify: {
    //   dist: {
    //     files: {
    //       '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js': [
    //         '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js'
    //       ]
    //     }
    //   }
    // },
    // concat: {
    //   dist: {}
    // },

    // Test settings
    karma: {
      unit: {
        configFile: 'karma.conf.js',
        singleRun: true
      }
    }
  });

  grunt.registerTask('express-keepalive', 'Keep grunt running', function() {
    this.async();
  });

  grunt.registerTask('serve', function (target) {
    if (target === 'dist') {
      return grunt.task.run(['build', 'express:prod', 'open', 'express-keepalive']);
    }

    grunt.task.run([
      'clean:server',
      'compass:server',
      'concurrent:server',
      'autoprefixer',
      'express:dev',
      'open',
      'watch'
    ]);
  });

  grunt.registerTask('server', function () {
    grunt.log.warn('The `server` task has been deprecated. Use `grunt serve` to start a server.');
    grunt.task.run(['serve']);
  });

  grunt.registerTask('test', [
    'clean:server',
    'compass',
    'concurrent:test',
    'autoprefixer',
    'karma'
  ]);

  grunt.registerTask('build', [
    'clean:dist',
    'compass:dist',
    'useminPrepare',
    'concurrent:dist',
    'autoprefixer',
    'concat',
    'ngmin',
    'copy:dist',
    'cdnify',
    'cssmin',
    'uglify',
    'rev',
    'usemin'
  ]);

  grunt.registerTask('heroku', [
    'build',
    'clean:heroku',
    'copy:heroku'    
  ]);

  grunt.registerTask('default', [
    'newer:jshint',
    'test',
    'build'
  ]);
};
```

Configuration for the express server:

```
    'use strict';

// Module dependencies.
var express = require('express'),
    path = require('path');

var app = express();


// Express Configuration
app.configure('development', function(){
  app.use(require('connect-livereload')());
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '.tmp')));
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'app')));
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/app/views');
});

app.configure('production', function(){
  app.use(express.favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
});

app.configure(function(){
  app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
  app.set('view engine', 'html');
    app.use(express.logger('dev'));
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(express.methodOverride());

  // Router needs to be last
    app.use(app.router);
});

// Controllers
var api = require('./lib/controllers/api'),
    controllers = require('./lib/controllers');

// Server Routes
app.get('/api/awesomeThings', api.awesomeThings);

// Angular Routes
app.get('/partials/*', controllers.partials);
app.get('/*', controllers.index);

// Start server
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port, function () {
  console.log('Express server listening on port %d in %s mode', port, app.get('env'));
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, its working. But, please see my **Update 1** in the last

Comment: Hi, it is comming from your server which have a bad configuration for html5. You have to configure HTML5 mode with Grunt. see here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16569841/angularjs-html5-mode-reloading-the-page-gives-wrong-get-request

Comment: I was checking that. Do I need to add the first answer code in my `Gruntfile.js`? I have installed `grunt-connect-rewrite` from https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-connect-rewrite. But I don't know what are where to ad in my Gruntfile.js

Comment: I gave you a random link about this subject. I will edit my answer and add my grunt file (with html5 enable). Just pick what you need for your application. I'm using express server to handle this.

Comment: Thanks. I am not using express server.

Comment: hmm, sorry for that, i edited the wrong answer... I hope it will help you anyway!

Comment: Actually where you are mentioning that html5Mode? I have same file with grunt-connect-proxy server side port and all. So I cannot replace the whole thing

Comment: I just added the documentation link for angular-generator-fullstack. Hope you find out your problem. Here is another link which explain the features of this generator : http://tylerhenkel.com/generator-angular-fullstack-1-0-0-available-now/.

Answer (score 0):

For the registration page problem, you have to add the registration page in routes and then use the route in the href tag. Like:

routes:

```
when('/reg', {
    templateUrl: 'views/registration.html'

  })
```

and href tag:

```
<a href="views/registration.html" target="_self">Register</a>
```

to

```
<a href="#/reg"></a>
```