# Path to resources (.css, .js) are invalid when refreshing a page after $routeProvider redirect in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a drill down from one page to another working.

$routeProvider as below:

angular.module('opalApp', ['opalApp.project','opalApp.services'])

```
/*, 'ui.bootstrap' */

    .config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
        $routeProvider.when('/home', {templateUrl: 'parts/opalhome.html'});
        $routeProvider.when('/projects', {templateUrl: 'parts/projects.html'});
        $routeProvider.when('/projects/:projectSk', {templateUrl: 'parts/project.html', controller:'ProjectCtrl'}); 
    })
```

It is the last $routeProvider to /projects/:projectSk I have the issue with:

I am presenting a list of projects, and providing a link to a detail page.  List of projects as below:

```
<div ng-repeat="project in projects | filter:search | orderBy:orderProp track by $index" >
        <p>Project:<a href="projects/{{project.projectSk}}">{{project.projectNm}}</a></p>
        <ul>
            <li>Disease Area: {{project.diseaseArea}}</li>
            <li>Tier: {{project.approvedPriority}}</li>
            <li>Status: {{project.planningStatus}}</li>         
        </ul>
    </div>
```

The href to projects/{{project.projectSk}}" is working and is taking me to parts/project.html and returning the data for the project.

ProjectCtrl controller is below:

```
opalApp.controller('ProjectCtrl',['$scope', '$routeParams', '$http',
     function($scope, $routeParams, $http) {
       $http.get('resources/project/projects/' + $routeParams.projectSk).success(function(data) {
         $scope.project = data;
       });
     }]);
```

My issue is, when I then do a manual browser refresh on the detail page

```
http://localhost:8080/misf-web/projects/75557
```

I get a load of errors in chrome as the path to the css and js files has been "amended" to have a /projects/ component in it.  And these cannot be found (not surprisingly as /misf-web/projects doesn't exist its a url rewrite)

```
    /misf-web/projects/lib/angular/angular.min.js
    /misf-web/projects/lib/angular/angular-resource.min.js
    /misf-web/projects/lib/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js
    /misf-web/projects/js/opalapp.js 
    /misf-web/projects/js/opalproject.js 
    /misf-web/projects/js/opalservices.js
```

In the main parent view these are all defined as below:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" media="screen" /> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css" /> 
<script src="lib/jquery/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
etc.
```

Note the lack of the added "projects" section in the URLs....

Any advice appreciated.

Regards

i

Comment: Have you enabled html5 mode?

Comment: yes  .config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

Comment: I am using tomcat, not sure if that makes any difference...but if my urls are all "js/file.js"...and I then navigate to a /projects/ through a url redirect....this will be an issue in anything I want to drive from urls, e.d. image urls

Comment: and if I make my urls "/js/file.js" with a forward slash at the start, I lose my app context name in tomcat in all the links.  i.e. it skips the app name no the server....

Comment: Ah. Use the <base href="tomcat-context"> tag in your index.html file.

Comment: Hi...I am already.  Without that I couldn't get any of the routing working.

Comment: Seems similar to this issue. Some sort of server side URL rewrite needed...not sure how to do that, but we are using a URL rewrite filter in web.xml it seems to strip out # signs.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22394014/how-to-correct-set-root-route-in-rails-4-for-angularjs/22460542#22460542