# angular query parameter with website url returns cannot get /

Tags: angular, query-string

I just wanted to come my angular site via

```
http://url.com/credit-card?paymentstatus=success&redirectUrl=http://google.com
```

But url gives me

```
Cannot GET /credit-card?paymentstatus=success&redirecturl=http://google.com
```

Here is my code

```
    .state('creditcard', {
        url: "/credit-card",
        templateUrl: "views/credit-card.html",
        controller: 'CreditCardCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'vm'
    })
    .state('error', {
        url: "/error",
        templateUrl: "views/error.html",
        controller: 'ErrorCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'vm'
    });
```

Comment: Are you trying to access the url from within your angular code? if so can you post some code?

Comment: No if I put this url to address bar, it cannot open my angular web page. Gave me that error Cannot GET /mysub?paymentstatus=success&redirecturl=http://google.com

Comment: are you using angular 1 or 2? and can you post your routes or a codepen?

Comment: Updated main problem

Answer (score 0):

To access sub routes without going through the SPA index page, you will need to implement server side redirects to each view. A ruby example/explanation is here: 
[How to correct set root route in Rails 4 for AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22394014/how-to-correct-set-root-route-in-rails-4-for-angularjs/22460542#22460542)

This is because the server when it receives the request looks for a page/folder to direct the request to. To be able to access directly without doing rewrites the direct url would be

```
http://url.com/#/credit-card?paymentstatus=success&redirectUrl=http://google.com
```

Comment: actually it was about version of ui-router and angular. After I update to 1.6.1 - it's fixed