# htaccess redirect for Angular routes

Tags: angularjs, .htaccess, redirect, web-applications, routes

I have an angular application with several routes, such as:

```
site.com/
site.com/page
site.com/page/4
```

Using angular's html5 routing mode, these resolve correctly when you click links to them from within the application, but of course are 404 errors when you do a hard refresh. To fix this, I've tried implementing a basic htaccess rewrite.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !OPTIONS
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.html [L]
```

This works for the angular requests, however when I try to load scripts or make ajax calls within my domain, such as:

```
<script src="/app/programs/script.js"></script>
```

This script doesn't load - it's request is redirected and it tries to load the index.html page as the .htaccess thinks it should reroute the request - not knowing that this file does exist and it should load the file instead of redirect.

Is there any way I can have the htaccess redirect the request to index.html (with the view parameters) only if there is not an actual file that it should resolve to?

Comment: Is `/app/programs/script.js` a valid file?

Comment: Yes, without my current .htaccess (as in the question) this file resolves properly.

Comment: This trick works on Angular 2 also.

Comment: Check out [htaccess generator for Angular](https://julianpoemp.github.io/ngx-htaccess-generator/#/generator). Plus [a very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76129016/cannot-access-api-from-apache-after-removing-hash-tag-from-angular-app).

Answer (score 177, accepted):

Use a snippet like:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.html [NC,L]
```

This will skip to the actual resource if there is one, and to `index.html` for all AngularJS routes.

Comment: This is almost perfect - it doesn't seem to handle routes with parameters, for example site.com/page/4, though I'm not sure why.

Comment: Can you show how your routes are configured or maybe check redirect log after adding a "RewriteLogLevel 9  RewriteLog /tmp/rewrite.log" to apache to see what is getting routed.

Comment: Turns out this worked fine - I just had some file references without a leading slash (/) and so were trying to resolve relatively in routes with parameters.

Comment: @rajasaur thank you very much - this is why I love stackoverflow. Helped me quickly solve what I thought I would be up all night trying to figure out.

Comment: @rajasaur I am working with grunt to load and configure my front end files. I am not able to route my angular requests to laravel as api's.I hav e posted my question here -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31698217/running-laravel-app-using-grunt-fails-to-start-session-on-local-environment How could I route my api routes and manage sessions?

Comment: Where and how do you put this htaccess file??

Comment: @JohnAndrews: Depends on how you configured apache, its just a set of rewrite rules, so it can go in any of VirtualHost, .htaccess or Core configuration

Comment: how to do the same thing in wildfly server

Comment: @atul, I would have a fronting server like apache or nginx and handle the static resources and routing over there. Only the proxied or backend requests will come to wildfly, everything else is handled by a frontend server.

Comment: Hi, In my case I have `http://www.domain.com/dashboard`. So the url has `/dashboard` then only I want to open the angular project. Please help me how to write `.htaccess` for the same. Actually I have 2 different angular project. 1st one will render on `http://www.domain.com` and 2nd one should run on `http://www.domain.com/dashboard`.

Comment: I am using grunt browserSync to serv up my content locally... Is there a version of this solution that will work for me? the `php -S localhost:port` will work for reloading ng-views but not the browserSync server.

Comment: I just wanted to mention that while the most common implementations of this type of script did not handle anchor scroll in my application i.e:`src="/foo#bar"`, this one does.

Comment: @rajasaur This doesn't seem to handle the routes with parameters.  My router looks like this ;                                                                         
      export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'activate/:activation_token', component: ActivationComponent },
  { path: 'reset-password/:reset_token', component: ResetPasswordComponent },

  { path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent },
];

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
  preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules,
  // useHash: true
});

Comment: can use RewriteRule ^(.*)/myapp/index.html [NC,L] for virtual hosts. where myapp will be in var/www/html folder

Comment: The "/index.html" in the last line needs to be preceded by an '.' to make the solution work in subfolders. Additionally "RewriteBase /YOURSUBFOLDER" needs to be added

Comment: In my usecase, I added index.html to the directory line: 
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.html -d` to ignore directories WITHOUT an index.html file to redirect to that route

Comment: @rajasaur perfect and work with parameter url like slug

Comment: not working when has more than 1 path ...

Answer (score 23):

There is a problem if app requested `directive` template file, but **file is missing**. In some case it caused app requested multiple script file in the `index.html`.

we should send `404` response instead of `index.html` file if file does not exist. So i add simple regex pattern to identify missing file request.

```
RewriteEngine On
# If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# If the requested pattern is file and file doesn't exist, send 404
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(\/[a-z_\-\s0-9\.]+)+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$
RewriteRule ^ - [L,R=404]

# otherwise use history router
RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```

Comment: if the file does not exist instead if doing `RewriteRule ^ - [L,R=404]` can I redirect to index.html using `RewriteRule ^ /index.html` or `RewriteRule ^ - [L,R=/index.html]` ? I am in a appserver environment and the paths are breaking quite a lot. Not used to such changes in .htaccess but just want to redirect 404 to index.html as well.

Comment: Yes you can skip the 404 part, but what's the point. This `.htaccess` approach is intended for missing asset / template file on angular directives, not missing path. If you want to handling missing path, you should configure router provider itself, or you can use router events.

Comment: I do not want a 404 handle for the .htaccess . I want to handle all that with index.html angular file

Comment: +1 for giving the only answer that uses `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}` in the RewriteCond which is required when you are within a VirtualHost - otherwise the condition will never be true!

Answer (score 10):

In my case i create .htaccess file like below

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*) ./index.html [NC,L]
```

**just added . before /index.html and add that file in my domain like https://example.com/subfolder and  it's works fine**

Comment: This work like magic for my angular project hosted on a cpanel. I can't thank you less. Thumbs up

Answer (score 9):

A poor man's solution (not using mod_rewrite):

```
ErrorDocument 404 /index.html
```

Answer (score 5):

Check out this link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/49455101/5899936
Create `.htaccess` file in root folder and pase this in the `.htaccess`

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks it worked for me. If it is sub directory, just add `RewriteBase /SubDir` instead of `RewriteBase /`

Answer (score 2):

I will provide another detailed htaccess file in case you need to :

- Considerate the baseUrl and default index file
- Remove the leading slash to manage :params

Here is my htaccess, very close, but more specific :

```
DirectoryIndex index.html
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /subDir
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.html [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a great *"Angular `.htaccess` generator"* available on [julianpoemp.github.io/ngx-htaccess-generator/](https://julianpoemp.github.io/ngx-htaccess-generator/).

The generator is open-source (the source code can be found on [github.com/julianpoemp/ngx-htaccess-generator](https://github.com/julianpoemp/ngx-htaccess-generator)).

The generated `.htaccess` looks like this by default and works fine for me:

```
# Generated with ngx-htaccess-generator v1.2.0
# Check for updates: https://julianpoemp.github.io/ngx-htaccess-generator/
#
# Transparency notice: Some parts were extracted from
# Apache Server Configs v5.0.0 | MIT License
# https://github.com/h5bp/server-configs-apache
# Extracted parts are wrapped by "START Extract from ASC"

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  
  # Redirection of requests to index.html
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
  RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
  # Redirect all non-file routes to index.html
  RewriteRule ^(?!.*\.).*$ index.html [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Successfully tested with Angular `13.0.3`.

Comment: I'm glad that the generator is helpful to you :) If you have any criticism or suggestion for improvement feel free to create an issue on the repository page :)

Answer (score 1):

In my case, we needed a more feature reach `.htaccess` configuration, like with:

- Forcing to HTTPS protocol (commented out in below).
- Translation of `Authorization` header to `HTTP_AUTHORIZATION` environment variable.
- Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS).
- And disabled caching for specific formats (commented out as well).

```
# If mod_rewrite is not present.
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
  FallbackResource /index.html
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  # Prefix for all rewritten routes ("index.html" gets "/index.html").
  RewriteBase /

  # Redirects to HTTPS protocol (once uncommented).
  #
#  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
#  RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L]

  # Make sure Authorization HTTP header is available.
  RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

  # Allows access to existing files or dirs.
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
  RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

  # Prevents treating the main-script as a route.
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  # Redirect anything else to main-script
  RewriteRule ^(.*) index.html [NC,L]
</IfModule>

# Enable Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)
#
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  Header merge Vary Origin

  # Allows any origin (just like "*", but works in more cases)
  SetEnvIf Origin "^(http(s)?://[^/:]*(?::\d{1,5})?)?" REQUEST_ORIGIN=$1
  Header always append Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{REQUEST_ORIGIN}e env=REQUEST_ORIGIN

  Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true"
  Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE"
  Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "*"
  Header always set Access-Control-Expose-Headers "*"
</IfModule>

# Disables Browser caching for production (edit pattern as you wish).
#
#<FilesMatch "\.(html|htm|js|json|css)$">
#   # Ensures "Expires" header is not overridden by module.
#   <IfModule mod_expires.c>
#       ExpiresActive Off
#   </IfModule>
#   <IfModule mod_headers.c>
#       FileETag None
#       Header unset ETag
#       Header unset Pragma
#       Header unset Cache-Control
#       Header unset Last-Modified
#       Header set Pragma "no-cache"
#       Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
#       Header set Expires "Mon, 10 Apr 1972 00:00:00 GMT"
#   </IfModule>
#</FilesMatch>
```

**Note:** We use `[L]` instead of `[L,R=301]` as the latter causes Browser to cache redirects permanently
(and even if someday that route is a file it will still get redirected).

Answer (score 1):

For Angular 2+, the following `.htaccess` file works.

Here is the `.htaccess` content:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  
  # Redirection of requests to index.html
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
  RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
  # Redirect all non-file routes to index.html
  RewriteRule ^(?!.*\.).*$ index.html [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

If you have not created the `.htacess` file yet, create it in `/public_html` directory.

Answer (score 1):

I struggled to find the perfect answer for the case when you are working with a **subdomain** in **cPanel**.

Here is what worked for me.
Lets say your main domain is `mysite.com` and you are using cPanel to host your site on the subdomain `subdom.mysite.com`. Add a `.htaccess` file in the same directory as your `index.html` file, i.e., in `cPanel file manager > subdom.mysite.com` directory (not in the `public_html` directory).
Then write the following inside the `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
# If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
RewriteRule ^ ./index.html
```

Answer (score 0):

Since angular is an AJAX application, html4 cannot implement it. All you have to do is activate the html5 mode in the .htaccess file.

```
angular.module('main', []).config(['$locationProvider', function($locationProvider) {
  ...
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  ...
});

RewriteEngine On
# If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```

Answer (score 0):

The use this snippet still works. I am using cpanel for a site I created for a customer using Angular 13. I was getting the 404 error when I refreshed the page and got the same 404 error when I tried to navigate to a different page from the browser.  I'm not sure when the ,htaccess code was generated on the hosting site or if it was with a tool or whether it was added when the SSL was created for this site.  I added the snippet above to what was already there and it worked!

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain name\.com$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://domain name.com/$1 [L,R=301]


  #Redirection of requests to index.html
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
  RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
  RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.html [NC,L]
```