# AngularJs Page Refresh Issue

Tags: angularjs, refresh

Getting 404 error when I do refresh on angular page. HTTP Status 404 - /product/P12345

Below is the my route configuration

```
MyApp.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {  
    $routeProvider
    .when('/product', {    
        templateUrl: 'components/product/product.html',
        controller: 'ProductCtrl'   
});
```

First time i'm hitting url as http://localhost:8080/index.html#/product/P12345 In the browser url get converted into http://localhost:8080/product/P12345
when i click on refresh button getting 404 error.

Not sure what causing the issue, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: what http server are you using?

Comment: Using apache http server.

Comment: then you need an .htaccess file! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22739455/htaccess-redirect-for-angular-routes