# How to reload page if html5mode is enabled in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, .htaccess, hashbang

I had made a SPA in angularjs, when I run it on browser it showed me '#' in the address bar. So I enabled html5Mode. This successfully removed '#' from the url but when I try to reload the page, it gives 404: page not found error. I tried writing in .htaccess from this url:
[htaccess redirect for Angular routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22739455/htaccess-redirect-for-angular-routes)

Nothing change.
I also followed grunt answers but that was also not helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Did you correctly enable html5 mode?

Take a look at the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16677528/location-switching-between-html5-and-hashbang-mode-link-rewriting#answer-16678065) to a question regarding html5 mode/hashbang mode.

Did you add `<base href="/">` to the head of your html?

Comment: yes @user3632710 I have correctly enable html5 mode as described in your link but the problem of reloading still persist

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup your server routes to return index file for all angular urls.

Usually you register your api at some special endpoint (as mysite.com/api/v1) and if url is not matching this pattern return index.html file with angular bootstrap logic.

This happens because without html5 mode all requests are sent to root server url (mysite.com/ even if link is mysite.com/#!/profile) but when you enable html5 mode, requests are sent as declared in angular so if you have '/' route with href to profile (/profile) and reload page from there (mysite.com/profile), request will be sent to mysite.com/profile and it will respond with 404 as it is setuped to return index file only for '/' url

Comment: thank you @Ihar you explained me very clearly. The issue still exist. I have now redirected the routes to index.html using following LOC
$routeProvider.when('/', {
           templateUrl: 'webapp/index.html'
       });
I still get 404.