# html5mode angularjs ui-router .htaccess re write rules

Tags: php, angularjs, regex, apache, mod-rewrite

I know this question has been asked many times in stack overflow, but I am not able to get the correct results.

I tried this link : [htaccess redirect for Angular routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22739455/htaccess-redirect-for-angular-routes)

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode

so basically ,i am using https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router for navigation in my app,

we have a url like this :

1. www.xyz.com/products <= this url **working fine,**  ( on hard refresh it is working fine )
2. www.xyz.com/displayOrders/12 <= this url is not working when we do
       hard refresh from browser. **WHY?**

also my nested views are not working :

3. www.xyz.com/message/notfication/12

what i wrote in .htaccess file is :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On
    # Don't rewrite files or directories
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]


  RewriteRule (.*) index.html [L]


</IfModule>
```

my base tag is this :

```
<base href="/"> and i also made html5mode as true in app.js
```

Answer (score 1):

You should write .htaccess like this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
# Don't rewrite files or directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule (.*) /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

If your project in subdirectory example: `www.xyz.com/shop/` You should write last rewriterule like this

```
RewriteRule (.*) /shop/index.html [L]
```

and base tag like this

```
<base href="/shop/">
```