# Missing Jars when switching from Glassfish to Apache Tomcat Webserver on Glassfish using Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, .htaccess, tomcat, glassfish, tomcat8

I am developing an Angularjs frontend which talks to a REST backend. I am developing using Eclipse and was using a Glassfish webserver.

I had the need to create htaccess redirect for Angular routes (see here: [htaccess redirect for Angular routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22739455/htaccess-redirect-for-angular-routes)) but to do this I need to change my webserver from Glassfish to Apache Tomcat since the htaccess stuff doesn't exist for the Glasshfish webserver.

When I created the new apache tomcat server v8.0, upon starting the log gave multiple errors for missing JAR files. These JARs were:

```
avalon-framework-4.1.3.jar
batik-css-1.6-1.jar
batik-ext-1.6-1.jar
batik-gui-util-1.6-1.jar
batik-util-1.6-1.jar
commons-configuration-1.5.jar
logkit-1.0.1.jar
nekohtml-1.9.11.jar
xercesImpl-2.8.1.jar
xml-apis-1.3.03.jar
```

Additionally, it wants the following JAR which doesn't not seem to be around anymore:

```
antisamy-1.3-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

A lot of the JARS mentioned above are old versions of the JARS. What can I do about the missing JAR that is not around anymore?

Also, how do I know if these JARs are the most current versions I should be using? (I added all of them I could find manually in the tomcat /lib directory)

Thanks in advance - I'm quite new to all this stuff so go easy on me:)

**EDIT 1:** I've included the non-snapshot version of the JAR as per unwichtich's answer. However this doesn't fix the error. Why would the Apache Tomcat v8.0 require such old JAR files to work, especially a snapshot jar? Where would one look to see where these JAR's are configured? Is it possible to know which newer versions of the JARs are compatible with my setup?

Answer (score 1):

> antisamy-1.3-SNAPSHOT.jar

First, you should NOT depend on SNAPSHOT dependencies, they can change the programs behaviour in the same version....

Second, SNAPSHOT versions might be seen as beta steps to the final release, so you can not expect that these SNAPSHOT versions are still available online when the final version was released.

A quick googling didn't suggest any old link to **antisamy-1.3-SNAPSHOT.jar**, but you may try this one: https://storage.googleapis.com/google-code-archive-downloads/v2/code.google.com/owaspantisamy/antisamy-bin.1.3.jar. This should be the final of 1.3 and if you are lucky it contains the same API as the SNAPSHOT version you used before. If not, you may have to update your code so that it works with the final.

There seem to be newer versions of the lib, you also may want to try them.

Comment: Thanks for that. Why should my server be using such old versions? How should I look to update them?

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean with your question. The server is using the JAR files you are supplying with your application, so your setup is the cause why specific versions of libs are used.

Comment: I never came across these JAR files when I was using the glassfish webserver on eclipse. These are only being asked for when I use the Tomcat server. Not sure what part of my application is actually using these.