# how to configure html5 urls with angularjs under apache + wsgi?

Tags: angularjs, apache, mod-rewrite

I am running an angular1.5 app with a python/bottle api that runs under apache2.2 + wsgi.  I want to use html5 mode to get clean urls (without the `#` in the url).

My question is how to use the apache `RewriteRule` to achieve this. My problem is that the apache server has two wsgi apps (one for the angularjs app and another one, unrelated). Can I create a RewriteRule that works for the angular wsgi app but doesn't affect the other?

Here is what I have now, with no `RewriteRule`:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess service user=www group=www processes=5 threads=25 home=/path/to/logs
WSGIScriptAlias /service /path/to/service.py #angularjs app
<Location /service>
  WSGIProcessGroup service
</Location>
#
WSGIDaemonProcess otherservice user=www group=www processes=5 threads=25 home=/path/to/logs
WSGIScriptAlias /otherservice /path/to/otherservice.py
<Location /otherservice>
  WSGIProcessGroup otherservice
</Location>
```

A link to the angular app might look like this:

```
http://example.com/service/task#/parm1
```

What I want is the link to look like this:

```
http://example.com/service/task/parm1
```

How do I use a `RewriteRule` to get clean (html5 mode) \urls in the first service but does not affect the `otherservice`?

Comment: You might want to check this answer, or modify it following that redirect logic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22739455/htaccess-redirect-for-angular-routes

Comment: A ``RewriteRule`` can be nested inside of a ``Location`` block. Have you tried that.