# Angular 7 Routes not working when deployed to Apache 2 HTTPD Server

Tags: angular, apache

I have been trying to deploy my Angular 7 application to HTTPD Apache 2 Server.
These are the steps I have taken:

1. Setup a Virtual Host for my project
2. Build --> ng build --prod
3. Created and configured .htaccess as instructed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43038060/deploy-angular-2-to-apache-server):

   ```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
     RewriteEngine On
     RewriteBase /
     RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
     RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
   ```
4. Configured my app-routing.module.ts like this:

imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes ,{onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload'})]

My main page works but when I try to navigate through other routes e.g. http://myhostname/users/crud, it won't work anymore.
Is there something I have missed here?

Thanks.

Comment: most probably you need to set `base href` in your angular app.

Comment: Have you took a look at this problem : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34816025/angular2-routing-deep-linking-not-working-with-apache-404 ?

Comment: Thanks @Wandrille. But I gave up on this since I am not an active PHP developer right now. I tried your answer but I used Springboot with embedded apache tomcat instead and I handled the routing via Zuul and application.properties. And it worked fine :)!

Answer (score 1):

```
Build --> ng build --prod --baseHref=/users/crud/
```

instead of

```
Build --> ng build --prod
```

Try the above code. That code work for me.

Comment: Thanks @user2455218. But I gave up on this. I tried your answer but I used Springboot with embedded apache tomcat instead and I handled the routing via Zuul and application.properties. And it worked fine!