# How to refresh AngularJs page without getting 404 error?

Tags: angularjs, apache

I have one page which the routing goes from. So if the user go from that root page e.g. `http://localhost/rootPage` and click on a button to go to `http://localhost/rootPage/subPage` that's fine however if the user refresh `http://localhost/rootPage/subPage` it will go the directory listing instead of the subPage.

So I wonder how can I make so the user still ends up in the subPage even though user refresh the page? Is it something in AngularJs or is it something I need to configure on the server?

Comment: I have same issue and as you said configured on the serverside.

Comment: seems like it is fine if I turn off the html5mode. however it is not possible with html5mode turned on?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [htaccess redirect for Angular routes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22739455/htaccess-redirect-for-angular-routes)

Comment: @lin Yea I know it is probably a duplicate. Your suggested SO does not solved my problem. Read my answer. Thanks for the minus anyhow ;)

Comment: @starcorn it wasn't me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found many SO answer on my issue. All of them are related to edit `.htaccess` file. None of them I found solved my issue though, so I googled and found [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_roIN2uNn68) Youtube video which also involves in editing `.htaccess`

Here's the snippet of what fixed my problem

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.html [QSA,L]
```