# angular includes not working after applying base tag to remove # in url

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have been working on Single Page Application in Angularjs. When index page loads I have loaded other pages into index page by using Angular ng-include.
Now it's working, But in the URL it's showing like http://localhost:8080/Index.html#/Home.html, I want to remove "#". I applied , after applying the base tag in the head tag "ng-include" not working. I tried other online stuff but I couldn't find any solution. I am using xampp server.

```
Thanks in Advance friends
<body ng-app="mainApp" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <header ng-include="'navigation.html'" ng-controller="headerCtrl">

    </header>
    <div class="container">
        <h3>{{Title}}</h3>
        <div ng-include="'leftNavigation.html'" ng-controller="leftDivCtrl">

        </div>

        <div ng-include="'rightPage.html'" ng-controller="rightDivCtrl">

        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <ng-view></ng-view>
    </div>
</body>

var app = angular.module("mainApp", ["ngRoute"])
    // Navigating external pages 
    .config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
        $routeProvider

         // $routeProvider .when( '/', { redirectTo: '/home' })
        .when("/Home", {
            templateUrl: "partials/Home.html",
            controller:"homeCtrl",
        })
        .when("/Aboutus", {
            templateUrl: "partials/Aboutus.html",
            controller:"AboutusCtrl",
        })
        .when("/Courses", {
            templateUrl: "partials/Courses.html",
            controller:"CoursesCtrl",
        })
        .when("/Contactus", {
            templateUrl: "partials/Contactus.html",
            controller:"ContactusCtrl",
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo:"Index.html"
        })
        //$locationProvider.hashPrefix('')
        $locationProvider.html5Mode({
            enabled:true,
            //requireBase:false
        })
    })
    .controller("homeCtrl", function($scope){
        $scope.msg = "Home Page";
    })
    .controller("AboutusCtrl", function($scope){
        $scope.msg = "Aboutus Page";
    })
    .controller("CoursesCtrl", function($scope){
        $scope.msg = "Courses Page";
    })
    .controller("ContactusCtrl", function($scope){
        $scope.msg = "Contactus Page";
    })

    app.controller("mainCtrl", ["$scope", function($scope){
        $scope.Title = "Single Page Application";
    }]);

    // loading external pages as includes, when index page loads
    app.controller("headerCtrl", ["$scope", function($scope){

    }]);
    app.controller("leftDivCtrl", ["$scope", function($scope){

    }]);
    app.controller("rightDivCtrl", ["$scope", function($scope){

    }]);
```

Comment: hey can you create fiddle link

Comment: After adding `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);` you also need to configure the server (basically .htaccess) to rewrite the url.

Comment: This link can help https://stackoverflow.com/a/22740184/2293313

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to define the `$locationProvider` to use html5 mode. 
So in your config phase just add this line:

```
 $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

Comment: i added it in the script

Comment: after applying <base href="/AngularSPA" /> tag Angular 'ng-includes' not working