# How to remove # from url in AngularJS and make the path working on reload/refresh?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I created a angularjs app using [yeoman](http://yeoman.io/) and below is my config

```
.config(function ($stateProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $stateProvider
      .state('state', {
        ....
      })

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

  });
```

and in`index.html` I have added `<base href="/">` inside `<head>` as given in [this solution](https://scotch.io/tutorials/pretty-urls-in-angularjs-removing-the-hashtag)

When I run the app for the first time using

`grunt serve`

Am able to navigate to all urls without `#`.
But when I copy and paste the same url in different tab `or` refreshing any path its showing

`Cannot GET /path_to_my_app`

How to solve this?

Comment: You need to serve the main HTML file through the server on the GET request so that for any URL the server first respond with the main index file so that the hashbang works on page reload

Comment: can't it be done form the angularjs app?

Comment: you need to fix routing manually **on the server**. Check your configuration file (e.g. [`.htaccess`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22739455/htaccess-redirect-for-angular-routes)) and add some rules that will resolve your routing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing the fragment identifier from AngularJS urls (# symbol)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14771091/removing-the-fragment-identifier-from-angularjs-urls-symbol)