# How to fix refresh problem in Angular Project

Tags: angular

I deployed my compiled Angular project as part of an existing project in JBOSS instance and am facing an issue in Browser Refresh

So for example
I am calling a short url which looks like

> http://x.x.x.x:x/contextPath/projectName

which redirects to

> http://x.x.x.x:x/contextPath/scm/projectName/index.html

(baseHref has been set to /contextPath/scm/projectName/)

Now on load URL changes to

> .../contextPath/scm/projectName/login

Loading is fine but then on refresh I get 404 as jboss does not recognise the new url

I thought using HashLocation Routing would solve it, but it avails same  result.

Any suggestions how to handle this would be helpful.

Comment: Problem is at your server. You need to set server to serve index.html file when navigating to /contextPath/scm/projectName/[anything]. I think this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22739455/htaccess-redirect-for-angular-routes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [htaccess redirect for Angular routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22739455/htaccess-redirect-for-angular-routes)

Comment: I did do the server setup, we have an existing project running and we need this to run as part of it. In the web.xml, URL Pattern has been mapped, which is basically a short URL and its redirecting to the index.html, all that is fine but on refresh it changes the url as i mentioned before. Maybe am missing something