# Cannot access API from Apache after removing hash tag from Angular app

Tags: angular, apache

When deploying an Angular v15 application to an Apache-based hosting, I had some issues with removal of `#` hashtag from the URL, because once it is switched off in the client, the server fails to load correct pages on refresh, and produces a 404 error.

I found it, [in the official documentation](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#server-configuration), which says:

> you must configure the server to return the application's host page (index.html) when asked for a file that it does not have

And I was able to find that I should add this section into the website's `.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
     RewriteEngine On
     RewriteBase /
     RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
     RewriteRule . index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

The issue I'm facing now, after the change, my API no longer works. It is from `/api/` root, starting from `mywebsite.com/api/login`, which now forwards me into `index.html`.

Is there a fix for this within Angular, to add `/api` exception, somehow, or is it a fix for the above script, to skip `/api` route?

---

This is the complete `.htaccess` file I have in the website's root, hosted on [A2](https://www.a2hosting.com):

```
# DO NOT REMOVE. CLOUDLINUX PASSENGER CONFIGURATION BEGIN
PassengerAppRoot "/home/vitalyto/ptintec-api"
PassengerBaseURI "/"
PassengerNodejs "/home/vitalyto/nodevenv/ptintec-api/16/bin/node"
PassengerAppType node
PassengerStartupFile src/index.js
# DO NOT REMOVE. CLOUDLINUX PASSENGER CONFIGURATION END
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
     RewriteEngine On
     RewriteBase /
     RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
     RewriteRule . index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

**SOLUTION**

Thanks to [Nigel Peck](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19137936/nigel-peck)'s answer, the correct addition to `htaccess` was as follows:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
     RewriteEngine On
     RewriteBase /
     RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/api/
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
     RewriteRule . index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Now my Angular v15+ can work fine without the annoying `#` in the URL, and with `/api/` requests.

**UPDATE**

Later on, I found there is a [whole generator project](https://gist.github.com/julianpoemp/bcf277cb56d2420cc53ec630a04a3566) for this! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is indeed. A fix to skip the `/api/` URLs. You can add this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/api/
```

So it would become:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/api/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.html [L]
```

Setting a condition for the rule to not apply if the requested URI starts with `/api/`.

Comment: This did it! Thank you so much! I don't get it why such a common task is so hard to find a solution for :)

Comment: P.S. See UPDATE in my question, an unexpected helper ;)