# Getting 404 error for an angular application deployed on cPanel when I try to access a specific page using route shared in mail. How can I solve this?

Tags: angular, deployment, cpanel

I have created an Angular application and it is working fine. If I try to access a specific page on the browser I can type the route and it will redirect me there. Now the backend shares this route in mail and I would like to redirect to this page.

Accessing the page however, throws 404 error.

I am using cPanel as my hosting service.

Any help would really appreciate. Been trying it for days now.

I have tried changing `.htaccess` to have `RewriteEngine` On  but still not working as expected.

Comment: I hope this help answer your concern: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22739455/htaccess-redirect-for-angular-routes

Comment: Thanks @KhaledAyed I was able to combine this and removed the /  in my router which was [routerLink]="['/home']" to [routerLink]="['home']". Need to find out whether this was the cause though.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Nginx configuration file. It should be similar to:

```
server{
    listen 80;
    listen [::] 80;
    server_name www.example.com example.com;
    root /var/www/example.com;
    index index.html;
    location / {
        try_files $uri$args $uri$args/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

Updated:

I have never tried that, but something similar to nginx config above but for .htaccess is:

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
      RewriteEngine on
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
      RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
      RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.html [NC,L]
   </IfModule>
```

Comment: I would have also prefered this but seems the Cpanel am using only give me access to do file transfers and the /etc/nginx  folder is not available. I only have access to .htaccess file.

Answer (score 0):

Add a rewrite rule to the .htaccess as below.

```
RewriteEngine On
# If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
 
# If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```