# Direct Link to URL with route params breaks AngularJS App

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Im having a problem when I have a direct link to a page that has a param after it. Links from the page work. Im working on a blog app.

localhost/blog loads correctly. On that page I have a link to localhost/blog/name-of-article. That link will load correctly. The problem is when I refresh the /blog/name-of-article page or directly go to it. It'll break and not load anything.

The Javascript console in chrome just gives the error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < " for all of the javascript files. I also have this problem when the url has a trailing / which seems like a common problem for angular. Not sure if it is related though.

relevant part of my routes.

```
app.config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider',
  function($routeProvider,$locationProvider){

    $routeProvider.
        when('/',{
        templateUrl: '/partials/home.html',
            controller: 'HomeController as HomeCtrl'

        }).
        when('/home',{
            templateUrl: '/partials/home.html',
            controller: 'HomeController as HomeCtrl'
        }).
        when('/blog',{
            templateUrl: '/partials/blog.html',
            controller: 'BlogController as blogCtrl'
        }).
        when('/blog/:name', {
            templateUrl: '/partials/article.html',
            controller: 'ArticleController as articleCtrl'

        }).
        otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });

         $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

}]);
```

I'm using Node/Express for the server and api for the angular app.

```
app.use('*', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
  console.log('page loaded');
});
```

I also have routes for /api/contact and /api/article.

Comment: What server are you using for serving the files ? Is it configured for enabling redirection to root page ? I believe the problem is with your server side. I am also working on a JS blog with AngularUI and NodeJS Express server. Your server might be serving the 404 page for requests. So you are getting the 'Unexpected Token' error.

Comment: Im actually using express/node too for the server. There a couple other pages that work though. An about and contact form that work correctly. The trailing / on those dont work either though. /contact works. Direct link to /contact/ won't. Ill add my express route code to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured out what happened for me. I was able to see that the angular app was making requests to the server from a different path when there was a trailing slash or the extra parameter. /blog/article was requesting all of the files from /blog/javascripts , /blog/stylesheets etc. which don't exist.

Adding

```
<base href="/index.html">
```

to the index.html file fixed the issue.

found in the answers here [Reloading the page gives wrong GET request with AngularJS HTML5 mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16569841/angularjs-html5-mode-reloading-the-page-gives-wrong-get-request)

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that your default html page, let's say `index.html` lives at the root and all the other dependencies are inside `/src`. This will have all your partials, javascript files, css etc.

You should configure your express server in such a way that for all the requests that target `www.example.com/src`, it should look for the resources in the `/src` folder in the root directory. The following line of configuration will tell express to do just that.

```
var staticDirectory = "/src";
app.use('/src', express.static(__dirname + staticDirectory));
```

And all the other requests should return `index.html`.

Configuring `express` server this way will make it return `index.html` for all the requests that don't target `/src`. If you have any other folders that have static content, you can configure `express` to work with them the same way as we did for `/src`.

Finally, your `express` configuration file should look like this.

```
var express = require('express');
var app     = express();
var staticDirectory = "/src";    
app.use('/src', express.static(__dirname + staticDirectory));
app.get('/*', function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
app.listen(9000, function(){
    console.log('Express server is listening on 9000. Yayy!');
})
```

I believe this will solve your problem. I tested this out with [this structure](https://github.com/mvpspl619/Venkatapathirajum.com).

Comment: I have my server file in the root folder. I have everything including my index.html in a folder called pubic. Inside the public folder is bower,partials,javascripts and stylesheets. I tried putting the index.html in the root folder and used /public instead of /src. I got a bunch of errors including the same ones. Did lead me to finding that with express and angular you need to do url rewrites so I'm going to look into that a bit more and see if it solves the issue.

Comment: Approaching the problem in the way as in solution would fix it. Please let me know if I can be of any help.