# AngularJS 1.0.7 in html5Mode get 404 error when refresh page

Tags: angularjs

I know there are some posts about this topic. I have read most of them, but I think I´m not skilled enough to understand what should I do.

I have an AngularJS 1.0.7 web application. I have just configured it to html5Mode to prettify my URLs. My URLs looks nice now, but I got a new problem I hadn´t before the change. When I first load my index page, I can refresh it without problem. However, if I navigate to some other page in example /about and then I refresh the page I get a 404 Error.

For example in this post: [Reloading the page gives wrong GET request with AngularJS HTML5 mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16569841/angularjs-html5-mode-reloading-the-page-gives-wrong-get-request/16570533#16570533) I have read that I should rewrite my urls in server side to my entry point, I guess index.html, but I don´t have any idea about what this means and how to do it.

Would anybody be so kind to provide a bit more detailed and practical example?

What does they mean when they talk about the server? I have an Angular application running on an Nginx server that sends requests to a Rails API that runs on a Puma server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the idea is to force Nginx to point all htpp requests to index.html and let the Angular do the routing in your application.

You didn`t post any configuration so here is the most basic:

```
server {
 listen 80;
 server_name foobar.com www.foobar.com;
 index index.html;
 root /var/www/mysite;

location / {
  try_files $uri$args $uri$args/ index.html;
 }
}
```

Comment: Mmm I´m only half happy. This works! and I can reload any page. However, now some other functionalities has stopped working. In example, modal panels. If I go to a page different that index with a link that opens a modal panel, if I click ok it, the modal panel opens but I´m also redirected to index. What am I missing?

Comment: You propably have some error in your Angular.js routes, I cant really tell anything else, without any code from you side, I have really done more than enough :)