# AngularJS 1.0.7 in html5Mode get 404 error when refresh page part 2 new error

Tags: angularjs

this is related to [AngularJS 1.0.7 in html5Mode get 404 error when refresh page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28611396/angularjs-1-0-7-in-html5mode-get-404-error-when-refresh-page) . But, actually the problem I depicted in that post is fixed, but after that, new errors has come. So, I have marked the previous one as ok, and I will explain my new error:

To summarize, page refresh is now working, however some functionalities related to links have stopped working. I post an example code:

**HTML**

```
   <li ng-show="logged" class="dropdown">       
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" style="padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 5px">
            <img ng-show="user.mainPhoto" src="//{{S3_BUCKET}}.{{PHOTO_SERVER_URL}}/img/users/{{user.id}}/{{user.mainPhoto.id}}.{{user.mainPhoto.mime}}" style="height: 30px; width: 30px;" class="img-circle"/>
            <i ng-hide="user.mainPhoto" class="fa-icon-user" style="font-size: 22px;margin-right: 5px"></i>
            {{user.name}}
            <span class="badge" style="background-color: rgb(41, 169, 223)" ng-show="userAlerts.length > 0">{{userAlerts.length}}</span> 
            <b class="caret" style="margin-top: 14px"></b>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1" ng-click="goToProfile()">{{'PROFILE' | translate}}</a></li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li><a tabindex="-1" href="" ng-click="logout()">{{'LOGOUT' | translate}}</a></li>
        </ul>                                       
    </li>
```

**JS**

login.js

```
$scope.goToProfile = function(){
    $location.search({});
    $location.path('/user-dashboard');
};
```

app.js:

angular.module('myApp', ['myApp.filters', 'myApp.services', 'myApp.directives', 'myApp.controllers'])
  .config(['$routeProvider', '$httpProvider', '$locationProvider',function($routeProvider, $httpProvider, $locationProvider) {

```
// use the HTML5 History API
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);   

$httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["X-Requested-With"];           

$routeProvider.when('/', {templateUrl: 'partials/home.html', controller: 'HomeCtrl'});      
$routeProvider.when('/about', {templateUrl: 'partials/about.html', controller: 'AboutCtrl'});    
$routeProvider.when('/contact', {templateUrl: 'partials/contact.html', controller: 'HomeCtrl'});
$routeProvider.when('/home', {templateUrl: 'partials/home.html', controller: 'HomeCtrl'});
$routeProvider.when('/user-dashboard', {templateUrl: 'partials/user-dashboard.html', controller: 'UserDashboardCtrl'});       
$routeProvider.when('/user-dashboard#tabProfile', {templateUrl: 'partials/user-dashboard.html#tabProfile', controller: 'UserDashboardCtrl'});
$routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/'}); 
  }])
```

Nginx config file (only relevant part):

```
server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        #charset koi8-r;
        access_log  logs/host.access.log;
        rewrite_log on;
        location / {
            root   /Users/Rober/Projects/yanpy/dev/yanpy/app;
            index  index.html index.htm;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
        }
```

When I click on the link that goToProfile, to navigate to user dashboard, I´m just redirected to index. Note: For other links or actions is navigating correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by removing the href="#". You have to remove it completely, if you just do href="" it doesn´t work.