# angular routing and html5 Issue

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to make a routing , it's working when I just clicking on links , but when I refresh the page , browser says not found ! I'm using html5mode , also when I set the # on url and search page manually it just works! what's the problem ?
this is `app.js` :

```
app = angular.module("app", [ "ngRoute" ]);

app.config(function($locationProvider, $routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when("/", {
        templateUrl: "partials/index.html",
        controller: "mainCtrl"
    }).when("/index", {
        templateUrl: "partials/index.html"
    }).when("/person", {
        templateUrl: "partials/person.html",
        controller: "personCtrl"
    }).when("/person/:id", {
        templateUrl: "partials/personShow.html",
        controller: "personShowCtrl"
    }).when("/about", {
        templateUrl: "/partials/about.html"
    }).when("/contact", {
        templateUrl: "/partials/contact.html"
    }).when("/coworking", {
        templateUrl: "/partials/coworking.html"
    }).otherwise({
        redirectTo: "/partials/person.html"
    });
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

Comment: Which web server are you using ? Apache ? Nginx ? you need to configure it to redirect 404 on index.html.

Comment: Can you create a plunkr ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is excatly [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28611396/angularjs-1-0-7-in-html5mode-get-404-error-when-refresh-page/), anwsered by me:

tl;dr

You need a webserver, like Apache, Nginx or something based on Node.js and you need to redirect all your http calls to index.html

Comment: Thanks for quick answer , I'm using http-server  , anyway do I have to use other webservers ?