# Page refresh gives 404

Tags: angularjs

I am using angular router for routing my app and I want to use the html5mode.

Routing is working fine, but when a refresh my page (on he browser), I get a 404 error.

Here is my routing code snipet

```
    angular.module ('app', ['ngRoute', 'home', 'login', 'admin'])

.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'app/components/home/home.html',
        controller: 'homeController'
    })
    .when('/login', {
        templateUrl: 'app/components/login/login.html',
        controller: 'loginController'
    })
    .when('/outils-de-gestion', {
        templateUrl: 'app/components/admin/admin.html',
        controller: 'adminController'
    })

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}])

.controller ('appController', ['$scope', function ($scope){

}])
```

What am I doing wrong ? Has anyone an idea about that ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS 1.0.7 in html5Mode get 404 error when refresh page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28611396/angularjs-1-0-7-in-html5mode-get-404-error-when-refresh-page)

Comment: did you implement URL Rewriting on server side?

Answer (score 3):

This solution works for angularJs.

1. index.html => Add   in  head tag.if your application is in folder then you need to add folders like:
2. config.js => add $locationProvider in function param and the code below:

   app.config(function($routeProvider,$locationProvider)
   $locationProvider.html5Mode({
       enabled: true,
       requireBase: false
   });
3. and your href should like ng-href="home" i.e. do not use #or !
4. thats it .