# Angular html5Mode redirecting to document root

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I have removed the # tag from my Angular application using html5Mode. But its redirecting to document root.

Ie, my application url is http://example.com/webapp/#/home.

When using html5mode, the new URL looks like http://example.com/home instead of http://example.com/webapp/home.

NB: Here my angular application files located in webapp folder inside http://example.com/.

I also tried by creating a `.htaccess` file in http://example.com/webapp/.

My `.htaccess` file contains

```
RewriteEngine   On
RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule     . /index.html [L]
```

How can I access my home page http://example.com/webapp/home ?

Thanks

Comment: Have you seen [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25961313/1896761)?

Comment: Yup, I tried several combinations in .htaccess file.

Comment: Hi @Saidh! If you found my answer helpful (or perhaps another answer), please [accept it & vote up](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this htaccess conf (place it in the root):

```
RewriteEngine On  
  # If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
  RewriteRule ^ - [L]

  # If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
  RewriteRule ^ /webapp/index.html
```

[Source](https://ngmilk.rocks/2015/03/09/angularjs-html5-mode-or-pretty-urls-on-apache-using-htaccess/)

Answer (score 0):

I could fix this by giving the html like

```
<html>
  <head>
    <base href="/webapp/index.html" />
    .....
```