# Html5Mode - refreshing the angularjs page issue

Tags: angularjs, node.js, cordova, angular-ui-router, cordova-cli

I am working on an angularJS app, which has URLs in the format (in dev) -

```
http://localhost:6001/#/home/index
http://localhost:6001/#/content/index
```

As this app, will also be available on desktop browser, I wanted the URLs to be without '#', so I added this in my app's config section -

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

Which works fine and URLs don't show '#'. But there is a problem now. On refreshing a particular page in browser, now I get this error -

```
Cannot GET /home/index
```

Are there any other changes required to get this working?

**Note:** This app is using cordova CLI and is hosted on a Node.js server.

Comment: Using html5 mode requires URL rewriting on server side. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16569841/angularjs-html5-mode-reloading-the-page-gives-wrong-get-request

Answer (score 1):

Try to put in your as your route:

```
app.get(*, function(req,res) {
  //return the main index file
});
```

This will cause any unmatched route to serve the index page and from there angular take care of this route.

Comment: I have route set up somewhat like this - http://pastie.org/10062399. Do you mean that I should create another route? Can you explain where to do what you said?

Comment: I mean in your node app not angular. if you are using express you can write what i showed you and if not just follow the same logic.

Comment: Oh. Actually the cordova library is currently taking care of running the app on node. I haven't programmed in node as such but I understand what you are trying to do. If you can lead me to any link or explain how to set it up, it would be great.

Comment: what do you mean cordova is running the node server? this is not what cordova does, they does not have a server running for you. you create your own server and connect the client to this server.

Comment: The cordova CLI which I am using for building cross platform app comes as a npm package and utlizes node as its web server. I am not sure how to tinker with its configuration.

Comment: I read somewhere that all configs are to be done in hooks folder, but don't know much in detail, so reading up more.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Make sure you have these lines in your server.js file

   ```
   var express = require('express');
   var app = express();
   app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public.build'));
   app.use(function(req, res) {
   res.sendFile('index.html', { root: __dirname + "/public.build" });
   });
   ```

   Why so? Please read here -  https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode
2. The first step resulted in my app in the following console.log message:

   ```
   Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type
   text/html: "http://localhost:8080/board/css/style.css".
   ```

   As you can see, the styles are trying to load from non-existent path (/board/ folder is not present in the app, it's one of the states in ui-router). 
   To fix it I replaced the following line

   ```
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
   ```

   with this one:

   ```
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
   ```