# How to configure node.js routes in a cordova app

Tags: node.js, cordova, cordova-cli

I am working on an angular/cordova app, wherein after removing `#` from Url and refreshing, the pages are not getting fetched and I keep getting error like -

```
Cannot GET /home/index
```

How can I configure node.js server to return index.html for any unmatched route?

Answer (score 1):

With [express](http://expressjs.com/) it should be quite simple:

```
app.get('/foo', function (req, res) {
    res.render('foo');
});
app.get('/:bar', _checkAuth, function (req, res) {
    res.render(req.params.bar);
});
app.get('*', function (req, res) {
    res.render('index');
});
```

Comment: Where is this to be included? Currently my cordova app is running on node server. It has a hooks folder to configure such settings but I am not entirely sure.

Comment: This is server side code. In case you're using express, have a look here: http://expressjs.com/guide/routing.html

Comment: I am not using express. Mine is an ionic app in which routing is taken care by angular and runs on nodejs by default. Please have a look at my previous question on this topic for which I got similar response, but not sure where to implement it - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29343436/html5mode-refreshing-the-angularjs-page-issue

Comment: Using html5 mode requires URL rewriting on server side. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16569841/angularjs-html5-mode-reloading-the-page-gives-wrong-get-request

Comment: I understand the solution, there is no issue with that. What I am struggling with is where to put this piece of code in a cordova app?

Comment: My understanding is that you have a server somewhere _outside your cordova app_. URL rewriting has to be implemented on that server. No changes necessary in your cordova app.

Comment: But won't that effect all projects running on node?

Comment: Well, only if all your projects use the same server/API.

Comment: I am not sure how express fits into an ionic app. If you have idea, please tell.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74106/discussion-between-sam-and-borisdiakur).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you shouldn't worry about the possible edit of URL, since a user cannot change the URLs while using the app. But yes, if you provide a wrong URL on any `anchor` tag, `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/')` will do that for you.

```
myApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/')

    $stateProvider.state('home', {
        url: '/',
        controller: 'homeCtrl',
    })

    $stateProvider.state('p1', {
        url: '/p1',
        templateUrl: "templates/p1.html",
        controller: "p1Ctrl"
    })
    ...
})
```

And may I know what is the content in your index.html page?

Comment: I am planning to use same app on desktops as well, so users can share links and get directed to that page itself. index.html is the usual default entry point in my app with head, body tags and references etc.

Comment: The issue is not with angular but with url rewriting. So i guess the changes are to be done at server.

Comment: I am unsure of why it wouldn't work. Unless you've made some changes with your Node? And just an opinion, ideally, whatever that doesn't change throughout your application must go in index.html, and then all the templates would go within the `ion-nav-view`. So if there is an invalid input of URL, you could rather take a user to some other template telling "404 page not found" or something.

Comment: I want to take the user to the same page, but as the path is not available (due to html5mode set), the rewriting has to be done on server.