# How to configure node.js in a cordova application

Tags: angularjs, node.js, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-cli

This is in relation to my question about changing node.js configuration in a cordova/ionic application - [How to configure node.js routes in a cordova app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29345020/how-to-configure-node-js-routes-in-a-cordova-app)

I didn't get a satisfactory answer to that. I also had a chat with couple of cordova/ionic guys on their blog, but they mentioned node.js cannot be configured by using express in this case and also did not have any clue to how it can be done.

So, my question is is it at all possible to do something like changing default port or url rewriting in node.js server when working with cordova/ionic applications?

Would love to know what you guys think.

**Elaborating** more -

Let's say I have a couple of routes like so -

```
http://localhost:6001/#/home/index
http://localhost:6001/#/content/index
```

As I didn't want the hash in URL, I added this in my app's config section -

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

Which works fine and URLs don't show '#' but on refreshing in browser, now I get this error -

```
Cannot GET /home/index
```

This is why I need URL rewriting to be done on server, which I can't seem to figure out.

These are my routes in app.js -

```
.state('home', {
            abstract: true,
            url: "/home",
            templateUrl: "app/home/home.html"
       })

.state('home.index',{
       url: "/index",
       views: {
           "index" : {
                      templateUrl: "app/home/index.html"
                     }
              }
       })

 $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home/index');
```

Comment: you seem to be confused... Cordova/ionic is a client side technology, node/express is a server side technology.  How the Cordova developers could tell you that their product would stop a server side technology from performing correctly just doesn't make sense.

Comment: Where do you get `Cannot GET /home/index`? Again: post some code where routes are defined.

Comment: also, this is not the second but the ***third*** question you have asked on the exact same subject.  If the answers being provided aren't solving the issue, clarify the question, don't continually open more questions with the same question body hoping for a different response.

Comment: @Claies Their blog was about how to create basic cordova hooks in node.js but not really specific to what I was trying to do. Also, I can add more, but their really isn't anything else to add. I hope we can have better discussion if you tell what is it that you don't understand here.

Comment: @AleksandrM I get the error in the browser page after refresh. I will add my routes too.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Html5Mode - refreshing the angularjs page issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29343436/html5mode-refreshing-the-angularjs-page-issue)

Comment: the problem is, you keep saying that the client side framework is causing the server side framework to not work, which makes no sense at all.  I suspect you aren't quite understanding how html5Mode works, and how the two routing engines you have are interacting with each other.

Comment: ok, so you posted the routes for your angular app, how about the routes in node?

Comment: I haven't set up any routes in node.js as it was not required. I have not worked a lot in node.js, so only have a basic understanding of it. But can you explain why node.js routes are explicitly needed?

Comment: Also, I am not saying client side framework is causing issues with node here. I just mean that this is not a node app as such and a lot of functionalities are added on top of it here like cordova cli/ionic etc. So, is it possible to configure it, that's all.

Comment: node is your web server.   either you set up routes there, or the project set them up for you.  in either case, the server routes are required to be configured properly for html5Mode to function.

Comment: That is the question itself. I didn't need to add server side routes when not using html5mode, but now I do. So, how to do it now in this scenario.

Comment: the same way you would in *any* node app.  if you post the routes that are in use now, we can tell you how to configure them.  if you don't post the routes, we can't possibly tell you what to change.

Comment: in the cordova project, under `www\js`, look for the `app.js` that is driving the node server process.

Comment: That is where I have put my routes and mentioned the same in my post. I am using $stateProvider for angular routing. There is no other place the routes are mentioned.

Comment: no, that's definitely an angular file.  there should also be a node file; even if you didn't create it, it **will** be there.  maybe a second app.js that is just in `www`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74336/discussion-between-claies-and-sam).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we discussed in chat, the Cordova_CLI project uses a fixed server for rapid deployment through `cordova serve` (or `ionic serve`).  This node server does not use express or other plugins to handle routing, it uses a script from the `[cordova-lib][1]` project.

The script provided for this development server does not take into account URL rewrites, so html5Mode would not work properly without modification of this script.  It could be a fork as simple as replacing the `do404` function logic to instead set `filePath` to `/index.html`.

another option would be running a separate web server (node+express or any other) and including the ionic/cordova scripts in the project.

Ideally, the production app would be running against a public server, and the Cordova_CLI server should only be an issue in dev environments.