# AngularJS application shows file structure when I refresh

Tags: angularjs, html, angular-ui-router

I currently have an AngularJS front end for my application.  I have used ui-router for transitioning between states.

When I enable HTML5mode and refresh the page, the application ends up serving the file structure, rather than the refreshed page.

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong.

I have given below a few snippets of my code:

These are my state definitions:

```
.state('home', {
           url: '/home',
           views:{
             'home':{
               templateUrl: 'home/home.html',
               controller : 'HomeCtrl',
               controllerAs : 'homeCtrl'
             }
           },
           access:{restricted: true}
       })


       .state('quote',{
         url : '/quote',
         views: {
           'quote' : {
             templateUrl : 'quote/quote.html',
             controller : 'QuoteCtrl',
             controllerAs : 'quoteCtrl'
           }
         },
         access:{restricted: true}
       })
       .state('profile',{
         url : '/profile',
         views: {
           'profile' : {
             templateUrl : 'profile/userprofile.html',
             controller : 'ProfileCtrl',
             controllerAs : 'profileCtrl'
           }
         },
         access:{restricted: true}
       })
```

Snippet from my app.js where i enable the html5mode:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode({
       enabled: true,
       requireBase: false
       });
```

snippet from my index.html:

```
<base href="/"/>
```

I have also attached a picture of the file structure I see when I hit F5.

Server background: I run my website on an AWS server and use NGINX + npm.

Regards,
Galeej

[image: Error I get when i hit refresh from my home screen]

Comment: This is almost certainly a web server configuration issue. In a single page angular app, all routes should go to the same entry point. I suggest you show your Nginx config.

Comment: May be the duplicate of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16569841/reloading-the-page-gives-wrong-get-request-with-angularjs-html5-mode

Comment: thanks for your inputs, we were able to figure it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by writing a server.js script using express js.

Reference: [Html5Mode - refreshing the angularjs page issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29343436/html5mode-refreshing-the-angularjs-page-issue)

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode

Please refer to the section pertaining to express rewrites.

Thanks,

Galeej