# AngularJS Not Loading on Other Paths

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, node.js, ngroute

I am sure this has been answered before, but I have no idea how to phrase this, so I was not able to find anything on Google.

I am writing a website using Node.js, Express, and Angular. My Angular app only loads when I visit the home page `127.0.0.1:8080`. When I click a link for a review (say to `127.0.0.1:8080/review/8ja9d8Kkjnmd`), I successfully route to my next controller and the next page in my angular app. However, if I manually enter the url and press enter, the node.js api just serves me the JSON I serve the Angular app.

So the Angular app takes this JSON and renders it for my view. How do I still load the angular page by manually entering the url and not just ping the node api?

I feel like this would be a common problem, and again I apologize because I am sure it has been answered time and time again.

This is the structure to my angular app

```
public/js
├── app.js
├── appRoutes.js
├── controllers
│   ├── MainCtrl.js
│   └── ReviewCtrl.js
├── views
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── home.html
│   └── review.html
└── services
    ├── MainService.js
    └── ReviewService.js
```

app.js is:

```
// public/js/app.js
angular.module('sampleApp', 
    ['ngRoute', 'appRoutes', 'MainCtrl','MainService','ReviewCtrl','ReviewService','underscore']);
```

appRoutes.js is:

```
// public/js/appRoutes.js
angular.module('appRoutes', []).config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    // home page
    .when('/', {
      templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
      controller: 'MainController'
    })
    .when('/review/:review_id', {
        templateUrl: 'views/review.html',
        controller: 'ReviewController'
    })
    .otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}]);
```

If there is any more code I need to post, just let me know.

Comment: You can either use `html5Mode(false)` or you have to update your server to server you the index page for every request.

Comment: your node api runs also on 127.0.0.1:8080? and has the same routing behavior as your angular app? it may help, if you disable the html5 mode just to go sure. chrome has a issue with the html5 mode too.

Comment: what advantages am I losing out on by setting html5 to false?

Comment: Anyways, this doesn't work. This just makes it to where angular is not loaded by hitting the link or by manually typing the url. So before, angular would be loaded by clicking the link, but not by manually entering the url. Now, angular is not loaded in either scenarios

Comment: difference is without it url's use hash in them like `#/routeName` and server doesn't see virtual directories in url

Answer (score 0):

I tried comment but I can't. Your question is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16569841/angularjs-html5-mode-reloading-the-page-gives-wrong-get-request). But basically that when modeHTML5 enabled, browser no way of knowing if the path is correct. Also I recomeindo you read the previous post

PS: Sorry for my english