# Laravel 5 + AngularJS html5Mode

Tags: angularjs, html, laravel-5, mode

I'm developing a project using Laravel 5 and AngularJS. I want to enable

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

and stop the page from reloading. The page doesn't reload when I set it to false and visit a link.

Here is my `route.php`

```
Route::get('/', function () { 
    return View::make('index'); 
});
```

Angular code

```
app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/feed.html',
        controller: 'fdController'
    }).when('/collections', {
        templateUrl : 'views/collections.html',
        controller: 'clController'
    }).otherwise({
        redirectTo : '/'
    });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

When I visit a link `html5Mode(false)`
`localhost:8000/#/ -> localhost:8000/#/feed` the page doesn't refresh

When `html5Mode(true)` and I visit 
`localhost:8000/ -> localhost:8000/feed`, the page refreshes and I get this error:

> Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.

Comment: Can you share more of your Angular code? how is your route configured and if you have things like target="_self" in your link? The PHP side might not be the problem

Comment: I've included it now

Comment: Please explain issues in more detail. Not clear what you mean by `doesn't reload`

Comment: Hey, did you find a solution to this problem ?

Answer (score 6):

I changed my route.php to

```
Route::get('/', function () { 
    return View::make('index'); 
});


Route::get('{all}', function () { 
    return View::make('index'); 
});
```

And added a base `<base href="/">` to my index.php
Everything works now and the page doesn't refresh.

Comment: using `Route::get('{all}')` is a very dangerous practice, it can lead to subtle bugs like requesting a javascript file and getting your index view instead.  you should consider using `App::missing` instead, since this will only fire on routes that don't already have a match to a defined route or resource.

Comment: I read around that ````App::missing```` isn't available in laravel 5

Comment: I think in this approach you can't resolve 404 error pages. this answer worked for me with a bit change: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16569841/reloading-the-page-gives-wrong-get-request-with-angularjs-html5-mode#answer-25961313

Comment: This isn't a great fix. If I had a AngularJS route like 127.0.0.1/this/is/my/blog then it would 404...