# 404 NotFoundHttpException on reload - Laravel + AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, html, .htaccess, laravel-5.1

so I googled how to remove the hashtag from the url when using angularjs with laravel. Mainly all resources were as follows:

1. Add `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);` to app.js
2. Update `base tag` in layout page which is `index.php`. Mine is as follows: `<base href="/myproject/public/">`

and it worked smoothly without any issues until I tried to refresh a page while working so I got the following:

```
NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:
```

I checked for existing [solutions](https://ngmilk.rocks/2015/03/09/angularjs-html5-mode-or-pretty-urls-on-apache-using-htaccess/#thecode) which mainly state to create `.htaccess` in the root directory, add the following:

```
RewriteEngine On  
# If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```

but it still works the first time only and whenever I reload, nothing works.

Another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30688090/laravel-5-angularjs-html5-mode) stated to add the following to the routes file but when I tried it I got the following:

```
FatalErrorException in Facade.php line 216:
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Foundation\Application::missing()
```

**UPDATE**

I updated the .htaccess file as follows:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
    <IfModule mod_proxy_http.c>
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} baiduspider|facebookexternalhit|twitterbot|rogerbot|linkedinbot|embedly|quora\ link\ preview|showyoubot|outbrain|pinterest|slackbot|vkShare|W3C_Validator [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _escaped_fragment_

        # Only proxy the request to Prerender if it's a request for HTML
        RewriteRule ^(?!.*?(\.js|\.css|\.xml|\.less|\.png|\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.gif|\.pdf|\.doc|\.txt|\.ico|\.rss|\.zip|\.mp3|\.rar|\.exe|\.wmv|\.doc|\.avi|\.ppt|\.mpg|\.mpeg|\.tif|\.wav|\.mov|\.psd|\.ai|\.xls|\.mp4|\.m4a|\.swf|\.dat|\.dmg|\.iso|\.flv|\.m4v|\.torrent))(index\.php)?(.*) http://service.prerender.io/%{REQUEST_SCHEME}://%{HTTP_HOST}/$3 [P,L]
    </IfModule>

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
    RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
</IfModule>
```

and on the server I updated /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf to be as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/myproject/public
        <Directory /var/www/myproject/public>
                AllowOverride All
                RewriteEngine On
                RewriteBase /var/www/myproject/public
                RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
                RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
                RewriteRule ^ - [L]
                RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

The hash is removed from the url but still whenever I refresh a page other than the home page, it gives 404 error. Any idea what's missing?!

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the url rewriting to this:

```
<rewrite>
 <rules> 
  <rule name="Main Rule" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url=".*" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
      <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />  
     <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
  </rule>
</rules>
</rewrite>
```

see the complete detail
[AngularJS HTML5 mode reloading page not found solution](http://www.advancesharp.com/blog/1191/angularjs-html5-mode-reloading-page-not-found-solution)

Comment: I am using Apache server so any idea how to write it in the correct syntax and format?