# Throwing cannot get error after enabling html5Mode in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, ngroute

I am using UI-Router for routes/states in my app and URLs were having "#" so to remove this , I used `$locationProvider` like -

```
function configState($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

Added `ngRoute` in module dependency and added `<base href="/" >` in my index.html.

**Problem** -

If I am using it as a normal app like in same tab and navigates to other state, it works **BUT** whenever I pasted the URL in another tab and hit enter its throwing `Cannot GET /app_views/contacts` URL is like -  `http://localhost:9000/app_views/contacts`

Though with hash in URL it works in both way manner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are likely getting this error because your server is not configured correctly. In other words when you manually enter `/app_views/contacts` it will make a request to the server for that page. For this to work properly you need configure your server to route all traffic to your `index.html` page in order for Angular to properly take over and display the correct view.

Here is a related post [Reloading the page gives wrong GET request with AngularJS HTML5 mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16569841/angularjs-html5-mode-reloading-the-page-gives-wrong-get-request)

Comment: What kind of server are you using?

Comment: I am simply running a bootstrap theme https://wrapbootstrap.com/theme/homer-responsive-admin-theme-WB055J451 and in docs its mention to run it via `grunt live` command after installing `grunt-cli`

Comment: Hmm well in that case I am assuming it is a node.js server. You are still going to have to fix it server side. You can probably dig in there and find how the app is being served. You will need to do something like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/18214539/3075624  

Once again I am only assuming this is a node server, it will be slightly different depending on what server you are using but regardless you have to point everything to you entry point which is most likely your `index.html` page.

Comment: I think I need to look at some grunt task....thx for the help :) +1 and added a tick