# routeProvider not matching any path with html5Mode enabled for $locationProvider

Tags: angularjs, route-provider

I am trying to match any path, which works when I dont have the HTML5Mode enabled, but it adds `/#` in the URL.

To get rid of `/#`, I enabled the HTML5Mode, which pulls the default URL but doesnt work if I refresh the page.

Here is my relevant code:

```
myApp.config(
    function($routeProvider, $locationProvider, RestangularProvider){

    RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl('http://someLink:3000');

    $routeProvider
      .when("/:path", { 
        template: function($location){
            console.log($location.path);
            // pull data from database corresponding to $location.path
        }, 
        controller: function ($scope, $location) {
          console.log($location.$$path  + ' called');
        }
      })
      .otherwise({redirectTo: "/link1"});

      $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);    // does not work after I add this and the app is refreshed
      $locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');  // does not help either
    }
);
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: You need server-side URL rewriting. Have a read of this ~ https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode. Also see https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location#server-side

Comment: possible duplicate of [AngularJS HTML5 mode reloading the page gives wrong GET request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16569841/angularjs-html5-mode-reloading-the-page-gives-wrong-get-request)