# Refreshing AngularJS stateProvider states

Tags: angularjs, html, angular-ui-router, angularjs-routing, page-refresh

I'm using StateProvider for routing in my website. Changing states from one to the other work, but whenever I refresh the page on any view, I get a 404 not found error (The requested URL /about was not found on this server.). For example, I have localhost/about (I set html5Mode to be true and require base to be false) but when I refresh it, it doesn't show that view anymore.

I am using this in my index.html page

```
<base href="/">
```

and this in my config file

```
state('about', {
    url: '/about',
    templateUrl: 'templates/about.html',
    controller: 'AboutController',
}).
```

What is the cause of this and how can I resolve the refreshing issue?

Comment: what does the console log say?

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16569841/angularjs-html5-mode-reloading-the-page-gives-wrong-get-request)

Also in that solution, instead of using htaccess, you could use the fourth solution in the comments.