# How to do url rewrite in node.js?

Tags: node.js, .htaccess

I'm having this url redirect rules-

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /#/$1 [L]
```

I need to these rules in express.js how can i write in express and i'm using loopback.io on my server.

Please guide me into this.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? URLs in LoopBack are based on the models you scaffold via `slc loopack:model`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have the same issue with Server Side Rewrite in Loopback.io, this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16569841/reloading-the-page-gives-wrong-get-request-with-angularjs-html5-mode)  is similar to the issue you are seeing

Plus this link [via github](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode) may help

```
app.all('/*', function(req, res, next) {
// Just send the index.html for other files to support HTML5Mode
res.sendFile('index.html', { root: __dirname });
});
```

Although I tried both methods the one above and this below none of these worked in my case:

```
app.use(function(req, res) {
res.sendfile(__dirname + '/Public/index.html');});
```