# remove #! from url in mean.js applications

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express

In mean js deep linking is enabled on default.how to remove #! in url of the mean js application ? I have tried using removing the following line in public/application.js.

```
$locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');

<base href="/">
```

and adding the following line to public/application.js.

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

But, when I type the url http://localhost:3000/signin to access the users list view it says:

> PAGE NOT FOUND

And on refresh says:

> THE SAME PAGE NOT FOUND.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS HTML5 mode reloading the page gives wrong GET request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16569841/angularjs-html5-mode-reloading-the-page-gives-wrong-get-request)

Comment: whatever given in that url nothing works any other idea??

Comment: What is your web server? Express / BrowserSync / something else?

Comment: express.js server and i m using nodejs

Comment: Then I suggest you have a look at this ~ https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-spa-router

Comment: it's not working not even now loads the index page

Comment: that url does not works

Comment: AngularJS HTML5 mode reloading the page gives wrong GET request