# angular-ui-router template and controller not loading

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to convert my app to use angular-ui-router but I'm unable to get templates/controllers to load. I wanted to have each route defined in each module rather than on the app/index.js file. I have configured the app to default to the login page, which will correctly change the url to /login when an incorrect url is provided. However, the login template and controller are not loaded and when I refresh the page I see Cannot GET /login. I don't see what's wrong with my code:

app/index.js

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode({
  enabled: true,
  requireBase: false
});

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');
```

app/index.html

```
<!-- content -->
<div id="main" ui-view></div>
```

app/login/login.routes.js

```
(function(){
'use strict';

angular.module('loginModule')
.config(function($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state('login', 
    {
        abstract: true,
        url: '/login',
        templateUrl: 'app/login/login.html',
        controller: 'loginController',
        controllerAs: 'vm'
    });
});

})();
```

app/login/login.controller.js

```
(function(){
'use strict';

angular.module('loginModule')
.controller('loginController', login);
...
```

app/login/login.html

```
<div id="login-content" class="col-md-8" ui-view>
...
```

Comment: your only state is `abstract`, and can't be transitioned to. https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views#abstract-states

Comment: Thanks! I was referencing the https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#style-y270 which included this attribute. My template and controller are rendering/loading now but when hit the /login url directly I still see `Cannot GET /login`.

Comment: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode

Comment: fixing the `abstract` attribute only solves the route issues on the client end.  As @Phil pointed to, you need to *also* ensure that the server knows to send those routes to the `index.html`.  The linked article has examples for many different servers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS HTML5 mode reloading the page gives wrong GET request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16569841/angularjs-html5-mode-reloading-the-page-gives-wrong-get-request)

Comment: I see, I need to configure nginx. Thanks, guys.