# Angularjs routing doesnt work when reloading the page manually

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am trying to reload the page mannually from the browser but it doesn't work  and says

```
 Cannot GET /rate/4
```

My route:

```
    angular.module('routing')

.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $routeProvider

    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'app/views/index.html'
    })

    .when('/rate/:cid', {
        templateUrl: 'app/views/rate.html'
    })


    .otherwise({
        'redirectTo': '/'
    });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

});
```

My assumption is that when I am reloading the main (index.html) is not loaded which is my base html file.

Comment: You will need a server side configuration since you are using `html5mode`.

Comment: @AlbertoI.N.J. I'm new to this... not sure what u mean by that

Comment: What server are you using?

Comment: I'm not using any server.... I've a spring backend and using angularjs without a server

Comment: If you have a backend then you need a server. E.g. apache, glassfish, nginx, etc.

Comment: @AlbertoI.N.J. is it possible to use a spring server?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS HTML5 mode reloading the page gives wrong GET request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16569841/angularjs-html5-mode-reloading-the-page-gives-wrong-get-request)

Answer (score 0):

You do not have an angular problem, you have a server problem.

You're essentially working with a single page application.

When the server receives a request for `rate/4` it must return `index.html` (or whatever the name that your main page is).

How you solve this will depend upon what platform you've implemented your server in.

For example, if you were running a node express server, you would have this kind of routing code:

```
app.get(/^\/rate\/.*/, function(req, res) {
    // This matches a known pattern for a client-side route
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '\\public\index.html');
});
```

Comment: can i use a spring server?

Comment: @user3100209 - I've never used a spring server. If it is a modern web server framework, there will certainly be some way you can configure the routing.