# AngularJS SPA application Browser refresh or F5

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router

In my angularJS application, I have five routes and dashboard route. After login into my application, dasbhoard is the first route from which all other routes starts. When I am in any one of five routes and hits F5 or browser refresh, my route is changing to default route. Can anyone help me. thanks

Comment: are you using `html5Mode`? and have you configured your server for push state support?

Comment: As currently written, you haven't provided enough detail for any reasonable troubleshooting of your issue.  Please consider creating a [mcve] of your scenario.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reloading the page gives wrong GET request with AngularJS HTML5 mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16569841/reloading-the-page-gives-wrong-get-request-with-angularjs-html5-mode)