# reloading angular page using ng-route in html5 mode does not return index.html

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

I am trying to use html5 mode for my mean app. The view router code in my angular script is as follows.

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

  $routeProvider
    // enumerate routes 
    // {tempUrl: req to send to express, 
    // cntrl: ng-cntrl to be used}
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: '/home',
        controller: 'mainController'
    })
    .when('/contact', {
        templateUrl: '/contact',
        controller: 'mainController'
    })
    .when('/team', {
        templateUrl: '/team',
        controller: 'mainController'
    });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
}]);
```

I have put a base tag in the head of my index.html file as follows:

```
...
    <base href="/" />
  </head>
  <body ng-app="mainPage">
    <header>
      <nav class="navbar navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
        <div>
          <div class="navbar navbar-top">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav float-right">
                    <li ng-class="{ active: isActive('/')}"><a class="link-btn" href="">Home</a></li>
                    <li ng-class="{ active: isActive('/team')}"><a class="link-btn" href="team">Team</a></li>
                    <li ng-class="{ active: isActive('/lessons')}"><a class="link-btn" href="lessons">Lessons</a></li>
                    <li ng-class="{ active: isActive('/media')}"><a 
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div ng-controller="mainController">
      <div id="main">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div ng-view></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
...
```

I have also added this rule to my web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>      
  <!-- indicates that the server.js file is a Node.js application 
  to be handled by the iisnode module -->
  <handlers>
    <add name="iisnode" path="app.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
  </handlers>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <clear />
      <rule name="app" enabled="true" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="iisnode.+" negate="true" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
        <action type="Rewrite" url="app.js" />
      </rule>
      <rule name="Main Rule" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

and in my app.js file:

```
app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/home', routes.home);
app.get('/contact', routes.contact);
app.get('/team', routes.team);
app.get('/lessons', routes.lessons);
app.get('/media', routes.media);
app.get('/signup', routes.signUp);
app.post('/new', users.new);
//app.get('*', routes.index); uncommenting the last line causes
//index.html to render without css, even though my stylseete is being served.
//this is confusing to me because I do want to always serve the index page
```

The problem is when I navigate to a page like /team or /contact then refresh, only the partial is served without styling. I want to serve the index page and then render the partial into an ng-route element. I understand this requires rewriting my node server code and have tried several rewrites without success.

I have seen this [Reloading the page gives wrong GET request with AngularJS HTML5 mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16569841/reloading-the-page-gives-wrong-get-request-with-angularjs-html5-mode). I see there are many questions about using html5 mode but I have tried many of the solutions without getting the desired behavior. Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

instead of providing express routing for serving html partials, add a folder to the public directory called partials and load them as static resources in the angular router:

```
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: '/partials/home.html',
        controller: 'mainController'
    })
```

now remove all your app.get('\req', routes.route) statements and provide one catch-all route to index

```
app.use(routes.index);
```

Now the page will always serve the index, regardless of the requested url. Refreshing the page will still serve the index.

The base tag in index.html is necessary. 'Main Rule' in web.config is unnecessary.

The hrefs in the navbar should have a slash in front of them, such as '/home' rather than 'home'. Everything should work as expected after making these changes.