# Angular view is not being updated

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Does anyone know where I am going wrong? I am trying to load up a new view on a section of the page in `AngularJS`.

I have the following code within `sidebar.html`:

```
<ul>
    <li><a ui-sref="MainPage({themeName:'theme1'})">Theme 1</a></li>
    <li><a ui-sref="MainPage({themeName:'theme2'})">Theme 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

Then my `module.js` file which contains all my routes looks like this:

```
var main = {
    name: "MainPage",
    url: "/:themeName",
    views: {
        "mainContent": {
            controller: "MainPageController",
            templateUrl: function($stateParams){
                var url =  'modules/main/template/' + $stateParams.themeName + '/home.html';
                console.log(url);
                return url;
            },
        },
        "sidebar":{
            templateUrl: "modules/main/template/sidebar.html",
            controller: "SidebarController"
        }
    }
};
$stateProvider.state(main);
```

When I look at the console I can see that the `url`being returned is correct but my view isn't updated on the screen.

Would anyone be able to point out where I'm going wrong, I'm not seeing any errors in my console and the application is loading fine.

Any help is much appreciated

The views I'm trying to load reside in `modules/main/template/theme1/home.html` and `modules/main/template/theme2/home.html`

the HTML for these views are as follows:

`/theme1/home.html`

```
<h1>This is theme 1</h1>
```

`/theme2/home.html`

```
<h1>This is theme 2</h1>
```

This is where I am using `ui-view`:

```
<body>
    <!-- SIDEBAR -->
    <div id="sidebar" class="col-md-2 animated fadeIn" ui-view="sidebar" ng-cloak>
    <div ng-include="modules/main/template/sidebar.html"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- HEADER -->
    <div id="header" class='col-md-10'>
        <img src='assets/images/logo.png' alt='' width='270' />
        <ul class="breadcrumb">
            <li class="active">{{ 'MAIN.NAVIGATION.LINK1' | translate }}</li>
            <li><a href="#">{{ 'MAIN.NAVIGATION.LINK2' | translate }}</a></li>
            <li><a>{{ 'MAIN.NAVIGATION.LINK3' | translate }}</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- MAIN CONTENT -->
    <div id="main-container" class="col-md-10 animated fadeIn" ui-view="mainContent" ng-cloak></div>
    <div id="footer" class="col-md-12"><p>This is a test site</p></div>
    <!-- SCRIPTS -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&sensor=false"></script>
    <script src="lib/all.js"></script>
    <script src="modules/app.js"></script>
</body>
```

Ok, so we've established that it looks like a routing problem on NodeJS. I am using `gulpJS` to start up my server like this:

```
gulp.task('server', function() {
  gulp.src([DIRDEST])
    .pipe(webserver({
          fallback : 'index.html',
          livereload : false,
          open : false,
          directoryListing: {
            enable: true,
            path:   'target/index.html'
          }
      }));
});
```

Comment: Can you provide your HTML view?

Comment: Seems that the sidebar controller is the controller that has the scope. You need the pass the values from the module that contains the new data to the scope of this controller. e.a. $scope.test = module.value; Then you bind your view to the test variable in this scope.

Comment: Can you also show the directory structure of your `home.html` relative to `index.html`

Comment: Also, are you using the HTML5 mode? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16569841/reloading-the-page-gives-wrong-get-request-with-angularjs-html5-mode

Comment: Ok I discovered the problem!

Comment: My gulp file was not copying the template files into the `target` folder. The application was requesting the correct template but as it did not exist it called the index.html file.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have defined `ui-view` where you want to render the template:

```
<div ui-view="mainContent"></div>
```

<strike>**Update**</strike>

I guess, you should use the `template` instead of `templateUrl`:

```
template: function($stateParams){
     var url =  'modules/main/template/' + $stateParams.themeName + '/home.html';
     console.log(url);
     return url;
}
```

**Tip**

Also, if you want to re-execute your `MainPageController` on view change (since both the states are same, just the parameter is changing) then you have to use `ui-sref-opts`:

```
<ul>
    <li><a ui-sref="MainPage({themeName:'theme1'})" ui-sref-opts="{reload: true}">Theme 1</a></li>
    <li><a ui-sref="MainPage({themeName:'theme2'})" ui-sref-opts="{reload: true}">Theme 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I've tried your suggestions and it hasn't resolved the issue unfortunately!

Comment: The controller seems to be loading my index.html file again within it.

Comment: @Javacadabra sounds like server routing problem

Comment: Where would I go to begin trying to fix that ?

Comment: @Javacadabra Can you please show your HTML where you are using `ui-view`

Comment: I've added that to my question now for you @ShashankAgrawal

Comment: @ShashankAgrawal.. `templateUrl` can be a function or a string. I think OP's usage is correct. If we change that to a `template` then it will be considered as the markup to insert into the view rather than trying to resolve that URL for markup

Comment: That's exactly what is happening @Arkantos, I was just about to post the comment saying this. Now the path to my template is being output as a string on the screen

Comment: Oh, you both are correct @Arkantos. I'll revert this. Which version of Angular UI router are you using?

Comment: That means your state config is working fine if you're returning the markup directly. I'm guessing something wrong with the URL that you're creating. Fire up the dev tools (F12) - Network tab and see if the AJAX call to `modules/main/template/theme1/home.html` is returning 200 or 404 response

Comment: Also, @Javacadabra Can you do a hard refresh by `Ctrl + F5` and try again. Sometimes, it's browser cache issues

Comment: @Arkantos it is returning a 200 response but the response itself doesn't contain HTML from the file I'm requesting, it shows the HTML from `index.html` and seems to reload it within the `ui-view` div...

Comment: I guess, @charlietfl is right. It looks like a server side issue of routing. There must be some rule which is redirecting the request of loading `modules/main/template/theme1/home.html` to `index.html`

Comment: Could it be this... `application.config(function ($urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
});`

Comment: I think that's not a problem. That default URL will kick-in when you try to use states that are not defined in your config

Comment: I can't think of anything within my application that would be causing this then. Could it be something to do with how I've set up my node server on my localhost?

Comment: Can you provide a plunkr reproducing this issue

Comment: @Javacadabra in browser dev tools network inspect request made for template. Look in response body. If url is correct but `index.html` content returned it is a server side routing problem

Comment: @charlietfl that is what is happening yes. URL is correct but response body is index.html. Can you point me in right direction of how to fix? I am using nodeJS localhost

Comment: It's your node routing. You need routing that returns templates. Could be incorrect order set up or you forgot to set up that route

Comment: Would it help if I showed you my `server.js` file where my server is configured?

Comment: Ok, I've added it to the question. I'm using `gulp server` command to start the localhost

Comment: I think, that is because, you have enabled the `directoryListing` option. Can you just remove that key `directoryListing` and try again.