# How to handle unknown route in AngularJS with C# Web Api backend

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, angular-ui-router

I am building a website that has an AngularJS front-end which communicates with a C# Web API. I want to configure routes within angular so that when you call /main you go to the main page etc etc.

I currently have set up my AngularJS routes like this:

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('app.main')
    .config(configure);

configure.$inject = ['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider'];
/* @ngInject */
function configure($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $stateProvider
        .state('main', {
            url: '/main',
            views: {
                mainbody: {
                    templateUrl: 'templates/main/cityScreen.html',
                    controller: 'cityController',
                    controllerAs: 'vm',
                },
            }
        });

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
}
})();
```

This route works fine when calling

```
$state.go('main');
```

inside the js code. But as soon as I refresh the page, or browse to /main manually I get the following message.

> No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:50561/main'.
>   
>   
>   No type was found that matches the controller named 'main'.

I assume this is because my Web API cannot find any route to a controller for /main. Which is correct. So my question is how can I set up my Web API to not give this error and instead return something so that my angular then can pickup the route and handle the page correctly.

Comment: This is a duplicate of [Reloading the page gives wrong GET request with AngularJS HTML5 mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16569841/reloading-the-page-gives-wrong-get-request-with-angularjs-html5-mode).

Comment: I've looked around but since many people use different servers, I havent really found a good blog post or guide on how to set this up for a Web-api only web project.

Comment: What version of ASP.Net/WebAPI are you using? Depending on this, you could add some middleware to understand the client-side routes and serve the HTML that contains the Angular code instead