# angular routeparams empty on api callback

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

Im trying to get some paramters from the urlcallback coming from an external authentication, in my angular projct using angular-route/$routeProvider

the api redirects to:

> http://localhost:8080/dist/?somevar=someval&val2=someotherval#/

Note the params come before #/
I try to read the get values with $routesparams like:"

```
$scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function() {
    // $routeParams should be populated here
    console.log($routeParams.somevar);
    console.log($routeParams);
});
```

This returns an emptyresult. however it i change the url to:

> http://localhost:8080/dist/#/?somevar=someval&val2=someotherval

it works, with the api I can give a callback url and I set it like:

> ?callbackUrl=http://localhost:8080/dist/#/

How should I get these parameters from the url whithout changing the callback url?

Answer (score 1):

In this case, the problem is with the Hashbang mode, which has a **hashPrefix** `#`. In the configuration phase, you have to enable **html5Mode** `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);`

> But this requires URL rewriting on server side and the HTML `<base>` tag.

Read more here: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location

So the explanation why it does not work for you this way, is when you give the `http://localhost:8080/dist/?somevar=someval&val2=someotherval#/` url to angular, it looks for the parameters after the `#`, and when you populate the `$routeParams`, it will create the parameters after the `#`.

Comment: Tried both, seems like the problem is the url but i dont know how I should get the url to be like the working example i posted.

Comment: I tried this but the problem is you cant navigate to the urls directly so an api redirect wont work. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16569841/reloading-the-page-gives-wrong-get-request-with-angularjs-html5-mode the server rewrite is a big nono to me.

Comment: Then I think it is impossible to do it with $routeProvider. But I think you should consider using htm5mode anyway.