# Angular js page refresh not working

Tags: angularjs, html

I tried to implement angular js state changing with html provider. But the page display 404 error when i try to refresh the page. what is the problem.
?

my state provider is

```
$stateProvider
    .state('home', {
        url: '/Edu',
        views: {
            'content@': {
                templateUrl: 'dashboard.html',
                controller: 'dashCtrl'
            }
        },
        params: {'registerData' : ''}
    })
    .state('dash_home', {
        url: '/dash_home',
        views: {
            'content@': {
                templateUrl: 'dash_home.html',
                controller: 'dashCtrl'
              }
        },
        params: {'registerData' : ''}
    })
    .state('login', {
        url: '/login',
        views: {
            'content@': {
                templateUrl: 'login.html',
                controller: 'dashCtrl'
            }
        },
        params: {'registerData' : ''}
    });
```

html5 conf is,

```
app.config(function($locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(false);
});
```

and also put

```
<base href="/">
```

in html page. but it didnt work.

**EDIT**

```
server {
    listen 80 ;
    listen [::]:80 ;
    root /var/www/Edu;

location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        root /var/www/Edu;
        try_files $uri /index.html;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the url you put in your browser?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reloading the page gives wrong GET request with AngularJS HTML5 mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16569841/reloading-the-page-gives-wrong-get-request-with-angularjs-html5-mode)

Comment: url:<a href="/login" title="Log In">Log In</a>

Comment: if you are running on localhost then comment out the html5Mode line. If it is on server then you should add the config file according to server.

Comment: Do you have .htaccess file in your project?

Comment: yeah... i will add my htaccess file in edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use the default redirection when the url is wrong or there is no state(just inject the $urlRouterProvider into config function).

Add a '/' state to redirect to your 'home' page, like this:

```
 .state('/', {
        url: '/Edu',
        views: {
            'content@': {
                templateUrl: 'dashboard.html',
                controller: 'dashCtrl'
            }
        },
        params: {'registerData' : ''}
    })
```

Add a default redirect ,like this:

```
 $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home');
```

Hope this helps good luck.