# $stateProvider angular add '/#' to my routes

Tags: angularjs, node.js, routes

I'm using $stateProvider to handle my routes in Angular 1 and I'm confused as to why my routes have an /# before they all start. I wouldn't mind but when I test those routes in Postman the routes return a 404 error. I'd like to find out why /# that gets added for my routes and get rid of it so I can connect my front end to my backend in node. I'm kind of new to using angular with node this so I'm not sure if I'm explaining my problem correctly.

Here's my code

```
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/main");    

$stateProvider
        .state("main", { url: "/main", templateUrl: "templates/main/main.view.html", controller: "MainCtrl" })
        .state("map", { url: "/map", templateUrl: "templates/map/map.view.html", controller: "MapCtrl" })
});
```

These are what my routes look like

http://localhost:8080/#/main

http://localhost:8080/#/map

but I want them to look like

http://localhost:8080/main

http://localhost:8080/map

Comment: # are used in SPA also known as fragment identifier to  find out which page you are looking..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get rid of `#/` you would have to set `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);` in one of your config files.

```
 angular.module('app', []).config(function ($locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
 });
```

For more information on html5 mode vs hashbang mode, have a look at the official angular [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location#hashbang-and-html5-modes)

Keep one thing in mind though, in html5 mode, your app might not be able to handle page refreshes properly without some server side url re-routing. More information in one of the stack overflow posts here: [Reloading the page gives wrong GET request with AngularJS HTML5 mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16569841/reloading-the-page-gives-wrong-get-request-with-angularjs-html5-mode)

Answer (score 1):

Man, just follow advises here and it's gonna be alright. [Removing the fragment identifier from AngularJS urls (# symbol)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14771091/removing-the-fragment-identifier-from-angularjs-urls-symbol).
And one more usefull link https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location.