# Angularjs HTML5 mode on doesnt work even after rewriting URLs on server side

Tags: angularjs, html, url-rewriting

In my `Angularjs` application the '#' was present initially in the URL. So I set the `HTML5 mode` for the app to true and also made the necessary changes all over the application code for URLs. PFB my code for that.

```
app.config(function($locationProvider){ $locationProvider.html5Mode({
    enabled: true,
    requireBase: false
});
});
```

Now as per [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16569841/reloading-the-page-gives-wrong-get-request-with-angularjs-html5-mode) I made the necessary changes in my configuration file. Those changes are as follows:

```
Options FollowSymLinks
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1 [L]
```

**The Problem:**

The application still won't work and it still doesn't refresh the URL i.e. I still get the 404: Page not found error.

Please help me regarding this.

Comment: try setting `requireBase: true` and inserting `<base href="/">` in your header of your index.html

Comment: Andrew , I did that. It still doesn't work. The problem seems to be in the rewrite rule that I am writing in my config file. I am not able to figure out what the problem is.

Comment: Just to be sure, your server must always send your initial index.html file. The routing is handled in angularjs

Answer (score 0):

Well, setting `requireBase: true` and inserting `<base href="/">`(or what ever else, depending on the env) in the header, and using this settings

```
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]

    # Rewrite everything else to index.html to allow html5 state links
    RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
```

works for me in every places that i ever used it. Your `DirectoryIndex` must be set to `index.html` or the name of the file you are using and this is very important, your server must always send your initial file.

The following is an example, of what i'm using right now, but it is in my pc, no public hosting.

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
    ServerName www.myproject.localhost
    DocumentRoot "d:/Work/myproject/"
    DirectoryIndex index.html
    <Directory "d:/Work/myproject/">
        Options +FollowSymlinks
        RewriteEngine On

        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
        RewriteRule ^ - [L]

        # Rewrite everything else to index.html to allow html5 state links
        RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]

        AllowOverride All
        Allow from All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```