# AngularJS page not found. Home page injected into index template but not other pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have my app.js and controller.js files stored in a js folder for the project, here's a snippet of each

app.js

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute','RouteControllers']);
myApp.config(["$routeProvider",function ($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider

.when("/", {
    templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',
    controller: 'HomeController'
}).
  when("/about", {
    templateUrl: 'templates/biography.html',
    controller: 'BiographyController'
    });
}]);
```

controller.js

```
angular.module('RouteControllers', [])

.controller('HomeController', function($scope) {

    $scope.title = "Welcome to Website!"
    console.log("HomeController: I was instantiated!")

})

.controller('BiographyController', function($scope) {

    $scope.title = "About"

});
```

Then I have my index.html file, the basics:

```
 <base href="/">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"        />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

<body ng-app="myApp">

<a href="/">Home </a>

<a href="/about"> About </a>

<div ng-view> </div>



<script src ="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/controller.js"></script>

</html>
```

My issue is that the text from the home page is shown when I load the page (as it should) but then when I click on about I get the following come up instead: 
'Page Not Found

This specified file was not found on this website. Please check the URL for mistakes and try again.
Why am I seeing this?
This page was generated by the Firebase Command-Line Interface. To modify it, edit the 404.html file in your project's configured public directory.'

The error in the console is simply 'Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()'

I have been searching for what the issue is but can't find one, the url when I click on about is 'http://localhost:5000/about'.

Comment: I think you can just remove the / from your href or try it with "#/about'
<a href="about"> About </a>

Comment: i think you should use ui-router , it better than ngroute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to add the `#` to your anchors

```
<a href="#/">Home</a>
<a href="#/about">About</a>
```

this will make it works. Also, you have the option to do it programmatically using the `$location` service

```
.controller('HomeController', ['$scope', '$location', function($scope, $location) {

    $scope.title = "Welcome to Website!";
    console.log("HomeController: I was instantiated!");

    $scope.goAbout = function() {
        $location.path('/about');
    };
}])
```

Now you can use the `goAbout` funtion in your template

```
<div>
  <h1>{{title}}</h1>
  <button ng-click="goAbout()">About us</button>
</div>
```

But, if you want to take advantage of the `HTML5 mode`, get rid of the `#` and have prettier url , at least in the browsers that support the `HTML5 mode`, then you need some updates in your code

```
myApp.config(["$routeProvider", '$locationProvider',
             function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
               $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
......
```

Inject the `$locationProvider` service and set `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);`

If you don't need the `<base href="/">` tag, then use an object like this

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode({
    enabled: true,
    requireBase: false
});
```

Now, your links need to change

```
<a href="/">Home</a>
<a href="about">About</a>
```

And you will have prettier urls. Please, notice that [`HTML5 mode` may need some server side configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38186723/angularjs-html5-mode-on-doesnt-work-even-after-rewriting-urls-on-server-side/39172864#39172864) in order to redirect all the navigation to your `index` page

Hope it helps